# Java Timestamp valueOf

Tags: java, timestamp

I came across a code snippet like this:

`Timestamp expiryDate = Timestamp.valueOf(dateStr + " " + "23:59:59.000");`

Here dateStr is a string entered by the user in a form, in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Now the behavior of Timestamp.valueOf is such that it converts non-existent dates into appropriate proper dates. Say 31st June 2008 into 01st July 2008.

How can I check in Java if the dateStr string is in fact a valid date ? I know I can manually do the check, but what I would like to know is whether any method is already available to do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  You simply set a format such as the one in your example and then call parse on your dateStr.

Comment: You must make sure that setLenient() is set to false, otherwise you wind up with the same issues as Timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Adam. It worked fine but not before calling the setLenient(false) on the SimpleDateFormat object. Thanks for that pointer, Spencer !

Comment: Also, be advised that SimpleDateFormat.parse() is *not* Thread-safe. So if you're doing this in say a servlet, you cannot have a static instance of your SimpleDateFormat, and will have to manage it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. Since `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`, it has got the same problems. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** You can define a `DateTimeFormatter` with `ResolverStyle` as `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, which is `ResolverStyle.SMART` by default.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.format.SignStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 1, 4, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .appendLiteral('-')
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .appendLiteral('-')
                .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .appendLiteral(':')
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .appendLiteral(':')
                .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendLiteral('.')
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, false)
                .optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "2008-06-31 23:59:59.000",
                "2008-06-30 23:59:59.000",
                "2008-6-30 23:59:59.000",
                "2008-6-8 23:59:59.000",
                "2008-6-8 2:59:59.000",
                "2008-6-8 23:5:59.000",
                "2008-6-8 23:59:9.000",
                "2008-06-30 23:59:59"
                
        ).forEach (s -> {
            try {
                LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf);
                System.out.println(ldt);
            }catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.printf("%s is an invalid date-time string.%n", s);
                // ...
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2008-06-31 23:59:59.000 is an invalid date-time string.
2008-06-30T23:59:59
2008-06-30T23:59:59
2008-06-08T23:59:59
2008-06-08T02:59:59
2008-06-08T23:05:59
2008-06-08T23:59:09
2008-06-30T23:59:59
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GvnQtt)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

#### If at all, you need an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`:

You can convert a `LocalDateTime` into `java.sql.Timestamp` using [`Timestamp#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) e.g.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(now);
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>