# Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL

Tags: java, sql, date, timezone, java-time

I need to be able to store a date (year/month/day) with no time component. It's an abstract concept of a date, such as a birthday - I need to represent a date in the year and not a particular instant in time.

I am using Java to parse the date from some input text, and need to store in a MySQL database. No matter what timezone the database, application, or any client is in, they should all see the same year/month/day.

My application will run on a machine with a different system timezone from the database server, and I don't have control over either. Does anyone have an elegant solution for ensuring I store the date correctly?

I can think of these solutions, neither of which seems very nice:

- Query my MySQL connection for its timezone and parse the input date in that timezone
- Process the date entirely as a string yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded that the best way in my current application (a simple utility using jdbc directly) was to insert directly as a string. For a bigger Hibernate app I might bother to write my own user type. Can't believe someone hasn't already solved this problem in some publicly available code though...

Comment: Yes, in your Java code, create your own type for dates, or just use a string. A java.util.Date object is a specific instant in time, and doesn't model your use case correctly.

Comment: I have a similar use case: an arbitrary date independent of year for correlating my data to seasonal data. I've stored month and day as integers rather than using a string, and I don't store any representation of year.

Answer (score 5):

**java.time**

This was indeed a problem with `java.util` date-time API until JSR-310 was incorporated in Java SE 8. The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value.

The problem that you have described was addressed with the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> where we have `LocalDate` that represents just a date. In the following sentence, the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) describes its purpose nicely:

> For example, you might use a LocalDate object to represent a birth
> date, because most people observe their birthday on the same day,
> whether they are in their birth city or across the globe on the other
> side of the international date line.

[A couple of pages later](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/date.html), it describes it again as follows:

> A LocalDate represents a year-month-day in the ISO calendar and is
> useful for representing a date without a time. You might use a
> LocalDate to track a significant event, such as a birth date or
> wedding date.

### Which datatype should I use for `LocalDate`?

It maps with `DATE` ANSI SQL type. The mapping of ANSI SQL types with `java.time` types have been depicted as follows in [this Oracle's article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html):

| ANSI SQL | Java SE 8 |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | LocalDate |
| TIME | LocalTime |
| TIMESTAMP | LocalDateTime |
| TIME WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetTime |
| TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetDateTime |

### How to use it in JDBC?

Given below is a sample code to insert a `LocalDate` into `columnfoo` (which is of `DATE` type):

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, localDate);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

Given below is a sample code to retrieve a `LocalDate` from `columnfoo`:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <some condition>");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Assuming the column index of columnfoo is 1
    LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class));
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You could zero out all time/timezone stuff:

```
public static Date truncateDate(Date date)
    {
        GregorianCalendar cal = getGregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, 0); // UTC
        cal.set(Calendar.DST_OFFSET, 0); // We don't want DST to get in the way.

        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the MySQL `DATE` type in your table and then essentially use the formatted string in your insert statement?  I'd think something like this would avoid any time zone adjustments.

```
INSERT INTO time_table(dt) VALUES('2008-12-31')
```

Comment: Hello, SQL injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify that your server and db are in different timezones, it seems to me that you have a problem with interpretation. If you zero out the date, or store as MM-dd-YYYY, which amounts to the same thing, are you storing the server date or the db date? If it's 11:00 PM on the server and 1 AM the next day on the db, which date is "right"? When you look at the dates a year from now will you remember which machines timezone the dates are dependant on?

These considerations may be a bit of overkill. But why not just store the dates in GMT (zeroing out the seconds if you like)?

Comment: Questioner didn't want to save a specific instance of time, just the date. A birth date in this case. So timezone becomes irrelevant, only when parsed should local timezone be interpreted. Setting the time zone to UTC/GMT is effectively the same thing. So I can't see like.. any point in your answer at all. Have I missed something? I feel I have to because you're probably a thousand times more experienced than I.

Answer (score 0):

The class `java.sql.Date` exists exactly for this reason, unfortunately it is very inconvenient to use, as it simply extends `java.util.Date` and you manually have to set the time part to zero.