# How to convert string type (java) and store in date data type in mysql?

Tags: java, sql, date

Im getting an error message while inserting values from the form. 
Error is **Column count doesn't match value count at raw 1**.
My 5th string value must be stored as **date** data type in sql.

```
String s1=this.txtUsername.getText();
String s2=this.txtPassword.getText();
String s3=this.txtName.getText();
String s4=this.txtAddress.getText();
String s5=this.txtContractEndDetails.getText();


         connection getcon = new connection();
         Connection conn;


    try{
        conn=getcon.creatConnection();
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into TravelGuide(username,password,name,address,contract_end_date)values ('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"'+'"+s5+"')");



        }
    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PanelTG, ex.getMessage(),"Error Occured",2);
    }
```

Here's my relevant table for SQL query.

```
  create table TravelGuide(
  username char(20),
  password char(20),
  name varchar(100),
  address varchar(150),
  contract_end_date date,
  constraint TravelGuide_PK primary key(username)
  );
```

**edited**

Im confused about

```
preparedStatement("insert into TravelGuide (username,password,name,address,contract_end_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Could u explain this furthermore..

Is this right? The codes which are inside ** marks are giving errors illegal start of expression and cannot find symbol.. Please help me..

```
try {
    conn=getcon.creatConnection();

    **String sql="insert into TravelGuide("+"username,"+"password,,"+,"name,"+"address,"+"contract_end_date)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?)";**
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.**preparedStatement**(sql);
    java.sql.Date dtValue = java.sql.Date.valueOf(s5); 

    stmt.setString(1, s1);
    stmt.setString(2, s2);
    stmt.setString(3, s3);
    stmt.setString(4, s4);
    stmt.setDate(5, dtValue);
    stmt.executeUpdate();                
}
```

Comment: DON'T USE DYNAMIC SQL!  You're opening yourself to SQL injection attacks.  Use a `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters.

Comment: You need to learn about PreparedStatements and bind variables and then do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370852/java-creating-a-date-object-from-a-string-and-inserting-into-mysql

Comment: My name is [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Where can I login to your system?

Comment: My apologies for the typo.  The method name is `prepareStatement`, not `preparedStatement`.  That would be the reason for the "cannot file symbol" error.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to construct the `sql` string that way.  You don't need to do a concatenation of literals.  You can just use one long literal: `"insert into TravelGuide (username,password,name,address,contract_end_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`

Comment: yeah.. now there aren't any errors, but it's still not working.. it will go to the catch block instead of try block.. can u help me..

Answer (score 4):

Inside the `try`, do this instead:

```
conn = getconn.creatConnection();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into TravelGuide (username,password,name,address,contract_end_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

java.sql.Date date = someFunctionToConvertYourDateStringToADate(s5);

stmt.setString(1, s1);
stmt.setString(2, s2);
stmt.setString(3, s3);
stmt.setString(4, s4);
stmt.setDate(5, date);
stmt.executeUpdate();

[and so on]
```

That way you are protected from SQL injection attacks and you don't have to worry about how to massage your string into a format a specific database requires for a `date` column.  The JDBC driver will handle that for you, given a `java.sql.Date` object.

Comment: +1. A variation would be to pass the date as a string and let MySQL figure it out with some to_date function it probably has.

Comment: Im bit confused about preparedStatement("insert into TravelGuide (username,password,name,address,contract_end_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); Could u explain this furthermore.. Btw i changed the conversion as this 
              java.sql.Date dtValue = java.sql.Date.valueOf(s5);

Comment: Sorry.  typo on my end.  it's `conn.prepareStatement`, not `conn.preparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into TravelGuide(username,password,name,address,contract_end_date)values ('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"'**+**'"+s5+"')");
```

why + ,i think i should be ,