# Calendar formatting issues

Tags: java, date, calendar

We're searching for information on how to format instances of java.util.Calendar and more general information and coding hints regarding transition from using java.util.Date to java.util.Calendar.

best,
phil

Comment: Has the [official documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) not proven useful?

Comment: If you really cannot avoid getting an old-fashioned `Calendar`, convert to a modern `ZonedDateTime` using `((GregorianCalendar) yourCalendar).toZonedDateTime()` and format the resulting object as shown in the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Answer (score 3):

My hint would be not to use either `Date` or `Calendar`. Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead. It's much, *much* nicer than the built-in classes. JSR-310 will hopefully, eventually bring something Joda-like into the main library, but for the moment Joda is your best bet.

If you *must* stick to `Date`/`Calendar`, see [`java.text.DateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Remember that they're not thread-safe though :(

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

If you are getting an object of `java.util.Date` from some API, your first step should be to convert it into `Instant` using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) which can be converted to other types of modern Date-Time API.

**A demo with the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);

        // Fixed offset
        OffsetDateTime odtUtc = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUtc);
        OffsetDateTime odtWithOffset0530Hours = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
        System.out.println(odtWithOffset0530Hours);

        // OffsetDateTime from ZonedDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odtNewYork = zdtNewYork.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odtNewYork);

        // LocalDate in New York
        LocalDate todayNewYork = zdtNewYork.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(todayNewYork);
        // Alternatively
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));

        // LocalDateTime in New York
        LocalDateTime nowNewYork = zdtNewYork.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(nowNewYork);
        // Alternatively
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));

        // Formatted output
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdtNewYork));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-14T19:22:13.544911Z
2021-07-14T19:22:13.544911Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-07-14T15:22:13.544911-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-07-14T19:22:13.544911Z
2021-07-15T00:52:13.544911+05:30
2021-07-14T15:22:13.544911-04:00
2021-07-14
2021-07-14
2021-07-14T15:22:13.544911
2021-07-14T15:22:13.586971
Wed July 14 15:22:13 EDT 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RlU420)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Some helpful answers using `java.time` API:

1. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.
2. [How to use `ParsePostion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67694505/10819573)?
3. [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67762712/10819573).
4. [SimpleDateFormat does not handle fraction-of-second beyond three digits in the millisecond part correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67728486/10819573).
5. [How to convert LocalDate to ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67890335/10819573)?
6. [`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573).
7. [Day-of-month with ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68141535/10819573).
8. [The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009408/10819573).
9. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).
10. [How to check if timestamp (epoch time) is of today's or yesterday's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626900/10819573)?

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>