# How to properly format the date?

Tags: java, date, time

The function shown below returns the date, e.g. "Sat Sep 8 00:00 PDT 2010". But I expected to get the date in the following format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm". What's wrong in this code?

```
String date = "2010-08-25";
String time = "00:00";
```

Also in one laptop the output for,e.g. 23:45 is 11:45. How can I define exactly the 24 format?

```
private static Date date(final String date,final String time) {
       final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       String[] ymd = date.split("-");
       int year = Integer.parseInt(ymd[0]);
       int month = Integer.parseInt(ymd[1]);
       int day = Integer.parseInt(ymd[2]);
       String[] hm = time.split(":");
       int hour = Integer.parseInt(hm[0]);
       int minute = Integer.parseInt(hm[1]);
       calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
       calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
       Date d = calendar.getTime();
       String dateString= dateFormat.format(d);
       Date result = null;
       try {
            result = (Date)dateFormat.parse(dateString);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you print out the return result? If you simply use `System.out.println(date("2010-08-25", "00:00")` then you might get `Sat Sep 8 00:00 PDT 2010` depending on your current date time format setting in your running machine. But well what you can do is:

```
Date d = date("2010-08-25", "00:00");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(d));
```

Just curious why do you bother with this whole process as you can simple get the result by concatenate your initial date and time string.

Comment: How can I get the 24 format at all laptops? Now it depends - sometimes instead of, e.g. 23:45, I get 11:45. But I need 23:45.

Answer (score 3):

> What's wrong in this code?

You seem to be expecting the returned `Date` object to know about the format you've parsed it from - it doesn't. It's just an instant in time. When you want a date in a particular format, you use `SimpleDateFormat.format`, it's as simple as that. (Well, or you use a better library such as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net).)

Think of the `Date` value as being like an `int` - an `int` is just a number; you don't have "an int in hex" or "an int in decimal"... you make that decision when you want to format it. The same is true with `Date`.

(Likewise a `Date` isn't associated with a specific calendar, time zone or locale. It's just an instant in time.)

Answer (score 2):

just use `SimpleDateFormat` class

See

- [date formatting java simpledateformat](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date%20formatting%20java%20simpledateformat)

Comment: As you can see I'm using SimpleDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); Date d = calendar.getTime(); String dateString= dateFormat.format(d);

Answer (score 2):

### The standard library does not support a formatted `Date-Time` object.

> The function shown below returns the date, e.g. "Sat Sep 8 00:00 PDT
> 2010". But I expected to get the date in the following format
> "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm".

The standard Date-Time classes do not have any attribute to hold the formatting information. Even if some library or custom class promises to do so, it is breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). A Date-Time object is supposed to store the information about Date, Time, Timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. The only way to represent a Date-Time object in the desired format is by formatting it into a **`String`** using a Date-Time parsing/formatting type:

- ***For the modern Date-Time API***: `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`
- ***For the legacy Date-Time API***: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

### About `java.util.Date`:

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date(); // In your case, it will be Date date = date("2010-08-25", "00:00");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
// sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")); // For a timezone-specific value
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

### Your function, `Date date(String, String)` is error-prone.

You can simply combine the date and time string with a separator and then use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the combined string e.g. you can combine them with a whitespace character as the separator to use the same  `SimpleDateFormat` shown above.

```
private static Date date(final String date, final String time) throws ParseException {
    return sdf.parse(date + " " + time);
}
```

Note that using a separator is not a mandatory requirement e.g. you can do it as `sdf.parse(date + time)` but for this, you need to change the format of `sdf` to `yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm` which, although correct, may look confusing.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date date = date("2010-08-25", "00:00");
        String strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }

    private static Date date(final String date, final String time) throws ParseException {
        return sdf.parse(date + " " + time);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-08-25 00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GNV6nW)

### Switch to `java.time` API.

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = localDateTime("2010-08-25", "00:00");
        // Default format i.e. the value of ldt.toString()
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDate = dtf.format(ldt);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }

    private static LocalDateTime localDateTime(final String date, final String time) {
        return LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(date), LocalTime.parse(time));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-08-25T00:00
2010-08-25 00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/cWalVZ)

You must have noticed that I have not used `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing the `String date` and `String time`. It is because your date and time strings conform to the ISO 8601 standards. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprise you are getting different date outputs on the different computers.  In theory, SimpleDateFormat pattern "H" is supposed to output the date in a 24h format.  Do you get 11:45pm or 11:45am?

Although it should not affect the result, SimpleDateFormat and Calendar are Locale dependent, so you can try to specify the exact locale that you want to use (Locale.US) and see if that makes any difference.

As a final suggestion, if you want, you can also try to use the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library ([DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)) to do the date manipulation instead.  It makes it significantly easier working with date objects.

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime( 1991, 10, 13, 23, 39, 0);
    String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format( date.toDate());
    DateTime newDate = DateTime.parse( dateString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```