# Parse is not giving me the correct date format

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, jdatechooser

```
public LigneReservation(Date dateArrivee, Date dateDepart,
        String categorie, int quantite) {
    super();

    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        this.dateArrivee = form.parse(form.format(dateArrivee));
        this.dateDepart = form.parse(form.format(dateDepart));
        String s = form.format(dateArrivee);

        System.out.print(form.parse(s));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.categorie = categorie;
    this.quantite = quantite;
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
ctrlRes.setLigneCourante(ctrlRes.creerLigne(dateArrivee.getDate(),
    dateDepart.getDate(), (String)listeCatCh.getSelectedItem(),
    Integer.parseInt(champQteCh.getText())));
```

So I first extract the date from `JDateChooser` fields and then I pass them to the constructor `LigneReservation`, the String `S` is showing me the correct format I want "yyyy-mm-dd" but when I parse it to a date, it gives me dates like this: `Wed Mar 13 00:00:00 EDT 2013`. How can I correct it ?

Thanks

Comment: [The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009408/10819573)

Answer (score 2):

> but when i parse it to a date, it gives me dates like this: Wed Mar 13 00:00:00 EDT 2013.

When you parse it, you get a `Date`. Using [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) *always* gives you the same format.

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```

If you want to format a `Date` in a particular format, use `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

(Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and its parsing/formatter facilities, which are generally nicer - as is the rest of the API.)

Comment: But that's what i used, problem is SimpleDateFormat .format returns a String while i want a date, so that's why i am parsing the returned String, or did i misunderstand you ?