# Typecast sql.date to calendar

Tags: java, date, casting

I have some code that uses the sql.date object to get the current date in the format: yyyy-MM-dd. I want to typecast that to a Calendar object that has the same format as the sql.date.

Here is the code for the sql.date:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date( now.getTime() );
```

Edit:

I want to know how to put this in a Calendar object. Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: [The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009408/10819573)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `java.sql.Date` doesn't *have* a format. It's just a date.

To convert it to a string, use a `SimpleDateFormatter` with the relevant format set - or just use `toString` if you definitely want `yyyy-MM-dd`. (Unfortunately it's unclear which time zone you should use - `java.sql.Date` is very poorly documented in this respect. I suspect it will use the default system time zone.)

To create a `Calendar` object with the given date, you can just use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sqlDate);
```

Again, a `Calendar` doesn't have a text format either - it represents a point in time in a particular calendar system in a particular time zone, but nothing about a textual representation.

Comment: This worked thank you. I did not understand how date formats and dates worked.

Answer (score 1):

Java `Date` objects (and note that [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) *is* a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)) don't have "formats". They represent an instant in time.

[`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) also doesn't have a "format".

What you're asking for doesn't make sense in java.

Consider using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format one of these things into a String:

```
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myDate);
```

or if you use a `Calendar` object (not recommended):

```
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat#format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29)

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                   .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Comment: So I should just replace the Date with the Calendar completely?

Comment: Yes, no need to construct `java.util.Date` separately. You'd get it from `Calendar#getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet.

```
public class DateTest {

public static void main(String[] arg){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //setting a valid date
    Date date = new Date(113,07,10);
    //prints the date as per format
    System.out.println("Date in YYYY-MM-DD : " +date);
    //sets the calendar with the date value in java.sql.Date instance
    calendar.setTime(date);
    //use simple date formatter to format the value in calendar instance
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println("Date formatted from Calendar instance : "+dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

}

Please let me know what happens!