# Java converting a Date to a different format

Tags: java, date

I have a date string in this format:

```
String fieldAsString = "11/26/2011 14:47:31";
```

I am trying to convert it to a Date type object in this format: **"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"**

I tried using the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
Date newFormat = sdf.parse(fieldAsString);
```

*However, this throws an exception that it is an Unparsable date.*

So I tried something like this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(fieldAsString);
String newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
```

However, this new format is now in the 'String' format but I want my function to return the new formatted date as a 'Date' object type. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have the date from here: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(fieldAsString);`

Comment: [The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009408/10819573)

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be under the impression that a `Date` object has a format. It doesn't. It sounds like you just need this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(fieldAsString);
```

(You should consider specifying a locale and possibly a time zone, mind you.)

Then you've got your `Date` value. A format is only relevant when you later want to convert it to text... *that's* when you should specify the format. It's important to separate the value being represent (an instant in time, in this case) from a potential textual representation. It's like integers - there's *no* difference between these two values:

```
int x = 0x10;
int y = 16;
```

They're the same value, just represented differently in source code.

Additionally consider using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) for all your date/time work - it's a much cleaner API than `java.util.*`.

Comment: Re the sentence in parentheses - I agree about specifying a time zone, definitely.  But specifying a locale - why would you do this?  If the format is `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` then there's nothing in there that's locale dependent.

Comment: @DavidWallace: The calendar system depends on the locale. I suspect the OP always wants to use the Gregorian calendar. (I'd *expected* the date and time separators to depend on the locale too, but apparently they don't in SimpleDateFormat.)

Comment: Wow, really?  So if I set the locale of a `SimpleDateFormat` to Iran, it will work with the Persian calendar?  That's kind of cool.  I see I have some experimenting to do. :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace: Not sure about the Persian calendar, but I believe you can get a Buddhist calendar for Thailand, for example...#

Comment: Thank you, Jon; I have a feeling I'm going to have some fun today.  Have an upvote!

Comment: Right you are.  It seems that the JDK will let me have a Gregorian calendar, a Buddhist calendar, or a Japanese Imperial calendar, depending on my locale.  I would feel really cheated if I lived in Saudi Arabia, Afghanistan or Iran.  I wonder who makes the decisions about what things to include in cases like this!

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711063/642706) is correct and complete.

Internal to java.util.Date (and Date-Time seen below), the date-time value is stored as milliseconds since the Unix [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). **There is no String inside!** When you need a textual representation of the date-time in a format readable by a human, either call `toString` or use a formatter object to *create* a String object. Likewise when parsing, the input string is thrown away, not stored inside the Date object (or DateTime object in Joda-Time).

## Joda-Time

For fun, here is the (better) way to do this work with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), as mentioned by Mr. Skeet.

One major difference is that while a java.util.Date class *seems* to have a time zone, it does not. A Joda-Time DateTime in contrast does truly know its own time zone.

```
String input = "11/26/2011 14:47:31";

// From text to date-time.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Pacific/Honolulu" ); // Time zone intended but unrecorded by the input string.
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).withZone( timeZone );
// No words in the input, so no need for a specific Locale.
DateTime dateTime = formatterInput.parseDateTime( input );

// From date-time to text.
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput_MontréalEnFrançais = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FS" ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
String output = formatterOutput_MontréalEnFrançais.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime as milliseconds since Unix epoch: " + dateTime.getMillis() );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC: " + dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
input: 11/26/2011 14:47:31
dateTime: 2011-11-26T14:47:31.000-10:00
dateTime as milliseconds since Unix epoch: 1322354851000
dateTime in UTC: 2011-11-27T00:47:31.000Z
output: samedi 26 novembre 2011 19:47
```

Search StackOverflow for "joda" to find many more examples.