# How to Get java.sql.Date in particular Format only

Tags: java, date

Got one problem wherein i have to convert one date format to another date format and have to return java.sql.Date in a particular format.

I have input format as MM/dd/yyyy and output format should be dd-MM-yy ..but unable to get it

```
    DateFormat orgFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    
    try {
        java.util.Date inputDate = orgFormat.parse("01/01/2020");
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(inputDate);
        java.util.Date outputDate = targetFormat.parse(formattedDate);
        
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(outputDate.getTime());
        
        System.out.println(" Sql Date "+sqlDate);
        
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**OutPut:  Sql Date 2020-01-01             // we need it as **01-01-20****

Comment: [The standard library does not support a formatted Date-Time object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009408/10819573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `System.out.println(" Sql Date "+sqlDate);` does is calling `toString()` on `sqlDate` and if you check it's implementation you will see it returns the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can override `toString` method or use formatter when displaying the date

```
System.out.println(" Sql Date " + targetFormat.format(sqlDate));`
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql Date only save the timestamp, and the timestamp of `2020-01-01` is same as    `01-01-20`.

If you only want print as `01-01-20` , modify your sout as

```
System.out.println(" Sql Date "+ targetFormat.format(sqlDate));
```

If you really need a class, you can try write a class whitch extends `java.sql.Date` and override `toString` method.

For instance,

```
public class DateV2 extends java.sql.Date {
    public DateV2(int year, int month, int day) {
        super(year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
        return targetFormat.format(this);
    }
}
```

and use `DateV2` to replace `java.sql.Date` in your code.