# Date formats difference between yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss and yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I am trying to parse a date `2014-12-03T10:05:59.5646+08:00` using these two formats:

- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`
- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`

When I parse using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` it works fine, but when I parse `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` a `ParseException` is thrown.

Which is the correct format to parse the date and also what exactly is the difference between these two formats?

Note : I cannot use Joda :(

Comment: Where did you read that you should use `XXX` to represent milliseconds? I'm not seeing it anywhere in `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc.

Answer (score 8):

use this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSX`

From [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API

```
//Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation        Example
  S         Millisecond             Number              978
  X         Time zone               ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

USE:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSX");
String date = "2014-12-03T10:05:59.5646+08:00";
System.out.println(format.parse(date));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Wed Dec 03 03:06:04 CET 2014
```

Comment: Don't use that format. Read my comment to the first answer.

Comment: @Michael-O **a)** actually first answer is mine. **b)** this code is working, [please check here a working demo](https://ideone.com/JUKAHq) **c)** can you please explain what you mean with *example is not valid since the tz offset is not extended* ?? thanks

Comment: I did not say that is not working. The format is invalid. Read on Wikipedia. You have to representations, basic and extended. If you write date and time in extended format, tz offset must be written too. Otherwise the input is not valid.

Comment: @Michael-O I don't get your point sorry, actually I don't care about what wiki says.... there are **millions** of date formats, and all are valids for someone, that's why exists parsers like `SimpleDateFormat`. So please be clearer, put some links or add your own canonical answer as far as seems you know more than us about this...

Answer (score 7):

Those are valid formats:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ       >>>  e.g.: 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX     >>>  e.g.: 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

**Edit:**
BTW, "X" refer to the (ISO 8601 time zone)

Comment: the first example is **not** valid since the tz offset is not extended.

Comment: I just ran it on eclipse for "today" and it produced:
2015-09-21T17:07:56.450+0300

Answer (score 0):

> When I parse using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` it works fine, but when I
> parse `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` a `ParseException` is thrown.
>
> Which is the correct format to parse the date and also what exactly is
> the difference between these two formats?

### Let's first look into `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`:

Check the following line (emphasis mine) from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
> **The method may not use the entire text of the given string**.

So, basically, the format, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` is considering only up to `2014-12-03T10:05:59` and ignoring the fraction of second and timezone offset information.

### What is wrong with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`?

In this format, you have put the symbol for timezone offset correctly but missed the symbols for fraction of a second.

### What is the correct format to parse it using `SimpleDateFormat`?

**The short answer:** None

**Long answer:** `SimpleDateFormat` can not handle a precision beyond milliseconds (i.e. 3 digits after `.`) correctly and therefore none of the formats can parse it correctly. The only way to get it correct is by keeping the digits after `.` up to three digits e.g. `2014-12-03T10:05:59.564+08:00`, `2014-12-03T10:05:59.56+08:00` etc. Let's see how `SimpleDateFormat` will parse `2014-12-03T10:05:59.5646+08:00` erroneously.

`SimpleDateFormat` considers the digits after `.` as the number of milliseconds (instead of fraction of a second, the way the modern date-time API considers). Thus, the calculation goes like this:

```
5646 milliseconds = 5 seconds + 646 milliseconds
2014-12-03T10:05:59 + 5 seconds + 646 milliseconds = 2014-12-03T10:06:04.646
```

Let's validate it using the code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2014-12-03T10:05:59.5646+08:00";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+08:00"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-12-03T10:06:04.646+08:00
```

### *java.time*

With the release of Java SE 8 in March 2014, the outdated and error-prone legacy Date-Time API (`java.util` Date-Time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) was supplanted by `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>. It is strongly recommended to stop using the legacy API and switch to this new API.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-12-03T10:05:59.5646+08:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-12-03T10:05:59.564600+08:00
```

### Isn't it cool?

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

By the way, for any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

#### I have faced a similar issue where I was unable to convert Time Stamp directly in Kotlin

so I wrote the code myself

First by Creating a Data Class to store

```
Data class TimeAndDate(
    val day : String,
    val month : String,
    val year : String,
    val hours : String,
    val minutes : String
)
```

Now for converting the String

```
 //for the type of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
// Here timeStamp is a String in the above format
        fun timeAndDateConverter(timeStamp: String): TimeAndDate {
            val day = timeStamp.subSequence(8, 10).toString()
            val year = timeStamp.subSequence(2, 4).toString()
            var month = timeStamp.subSequence(5, 7).toString()
            when (month) {
                "01" -> month = "Jan"
                "02" -> month = "Feb"
                "03" -> month = "Mar"
                "04" -> month = "Apr"
                "05" -> month = "May"
                "06" -> month = "Jun"
                "07" -> month = "Jul"
                "08" -> month = "Aug"
                "09" -> month = "Sep"
                "10" -> month = "Oct"
                "11" -> month = "Nov"
                "12" -> month = "Dec"

            }
            val hours = timeStamp.subSequence(11, 13).toString()
            val minutes = timeStamp.subSequence(14, 16).toString()

            return TimeAndDate(
                day = day,
                month = month,
                year = year,
                hours = hours,
                minutes = minutes
            )

        }
```

This function will return the data class from where we can get all individual elements