# Convert Java Date to specific time zone according to stored time zone in groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, java-8

I stored timezone in string format in my database and I am rendering a table in which I have start date and end date and below is my implementation

Suppose I have time zone Asia/Colombo
I am converting a date **2021-06-08T00:00:00** to time zone of Asia/Colombo

By this logic, I am getting date in this format Tue Jun 08 00:00:00 IST 2021 but
I want output in this format **2021-06-08T00:00:00 (with specific timezone)**

What should I change in the current implementation to get desired output?

and also whenever I am returning date in Date type it is getting changed

Which is better returning date in string or Date

```
        List<TimeZone> timeZoneList = TimeZone.findAll()
        String zone = timeZoneList ? timeZoneList[0]?.currentTimeZone : null
        String zoneId = zone ? TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone).ID : TimeZone.getDefault().ID

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dateToConvert);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId));
        String convertedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime())
        println("converted date in string format ----->>>>>>>>>>> " + convertedDate)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to store the date only, not the time, is that correct? And if so, has your database got a `date` data type? Use it. And then use `LocalDate` in Java.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the input date time into LocalDateTime and convert ZoneDateTime

```
 String inputDate = "2021-06-08T00:00:00";

 ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDate).atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));

 System.out.println(zonedDateTime); //2021-06-08T00:00+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-06-08T00:00:00";
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtColombo = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));
        System.out.println(zdtColombo);

        // Output in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(zdtColombo);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-08T05:30+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
2021-06-08 05:30:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gkIsvH)

If your column type is `DATE`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573).

If your column type is `TIME WITH TIMEZONE`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573).

### How to convert `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime`?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample LocalDate (to be retrieved with JDBC)
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, 6, 8);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtColombo = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);
        System.out.println(zdtColombo);

        // Output in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdtUtc));
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdtColombo));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-08T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-06-08T05:30+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
2021-06-08 00:00:00
2021-06-08 05:30:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XZRBEF)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>