# Generating UTC Time in java

Tags: java, datetime, date

I want to get the UTC time for 01/01/2100 in Java to '2100-01-01 00:00:00'. I am getting "2100-01-01 00:08:00". Any idea, how to correct this.

```
public Date getFinalTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date finalTime = null;

    try
    {
        finalTime = df.parse("01/01/2100");            
    } catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    calendar.setTime(finalTime);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It’s weird that you get 8 minutes ahead, I cannot explain. I wish you had shown the code producing `2100-01-01 00:08:00` since the issue may be there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the time zone for the SimpleDateFormat as well - currently that's parsing midnight *local time* which is ending up as 8am UTC.

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
df.setTimeZone(utc);
Date finalTime = null;

try
{
    finalTime = df.parse("01/01/2100");            
} catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

calendar.setTime(finalTime);
```

As ever though, I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is far more capable in general. I'd be happy to translate your example into Joda Time if you want.

Additionally, I see you're returning `calendar.getTime()` - that's just the same as returning `finalTime` as soon as you've computed it.

Finally, just catching a `ParseException` and carrying on as if it didn't happen is a very bad idea. I'm hoping this is just sample code and it doesn't reflect your real method. Likewise I'm assuming that *really* you'll be parsing some other text - if you're not, then as Eyal said, you should just call methods on `Calendar` directly. (Or, again, use Joda Time.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the time zone of the SimpleDateFormat object as well, otherwise it assumes the default time zone.

Anyway, it seems like using only a Calendar is enough in your case. Use its setters to set the right values for all fields (year, month, day, hour, etc), and then retrieve the time.

Comment: If the OP only has a string as input, it would make sense to use the built-in classes to do the parsing rather than parsing it himself, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I didn't understand from his explanation that he is given a variable string as an input. I assumed it is a fixed value, detoting some time limit (year 2100).

Comment: I assumed it was just a sample - if he doesn't actually want to parse text, it would certainly be odd (and wrong) to use SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "01/01/2100";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfInput)
                                .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        // Default format
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Getting and displaying LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // A custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Alternatively dtfOutput.format(ldt);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
        
        // Converting to some other types
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2100-01-01T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
2100-01-01T00:00
2100-01-01 00:00:00
2100-01-01T00:00Z
2100-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nZhmVv)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** The Date-Time without timezone name or timezone offset should be represented by [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) (which is used for events that are normally not represented with timezone information). In this sense, `LocalDateTime` is useless in this case and you should use `ZonedDateTime` itself or `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. I recommend you also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) if you are dealing with JDBC.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Like Arvind Kumar Avinash I very clearly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. If what you want is a fixed (constant) date and time, use `OffsetDateTime.of()`.

```
    OffsetDateTime finalTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(finalTime);
```

Output:

> 2100-01-01T00:00Z

The trailing `Z` means UTC.

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);

DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateformat.setTimeZone(utc);
```

Timezone needs to be set.

Comment: Are you contributing anything that isn’t already in a couple of the other answers? Also, while it was OK to use `TimeZone`, `Calendar` `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` 11 years ago when this question was asked, those classes have very long now been replaced with [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).