# How to get current UTC timestamp in seconds

Tags: java, timestamp

How to get current time-stamp in UTC/GMT and then How to convert this time-stamp into seconds ? Itry this but its thrw exception

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdfu  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm");
    Date udate = sdfu.parse(dateAndTimeUTC);
    long timeInMillisSinceEpoch123 = udate.getTime(); 
    long durationinSeconds2 = timeInMillisSinceEpoch123 / 1000;
    System.out.println("Time in Seconds UTC: " + durationinSeconds2);
```

Is there any better way to convert UTC/GMT time-stamp into seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366356/generating-utc-time-in-java

Answer (score 50):

get current seconds system
`long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;`

Comment: @Limnic Your statement is false. The [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) states "**Returns:**<br />the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC." The time difference since UTC is in UTC time and is not affected by time zones.

Answer (score 36):

With Java 8+, you can use:

```java
Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
```