# get next day java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date

I have a Date object (`java.sql.Date`). I need to get 12 at night of that day. So I can create a time period from current time to end of the day.

How can I calculate that time with `java.sql.Date`. Please send me an example.

Comment: have you tried anything with which I can help you? use google to get example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a *much* better date and time API than the one in Java.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = ...;
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(sqlDate.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
LocalDate tomorrow = date.plusDays(1);

DateTime startOfDay = tomorrow.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.UTC);

java.sql.Date sqlTomorrow = new java.sql.Date(startOfDay.getMillis());
```

Note that this assumes UTC everywhere... whereas I suspect you want midnight *local time* in which case you'll need to specify the time zone. Also note that midnight doesn't always occur on every day in all time zones due to daylight saving time - the above code will give you the start of the day instead.

Answer (score 12):

Using [java.util.Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = ...;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sqlDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
java.sql.Date sqlTommorow = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
java.sql.Date now = new java.sql.Date( new java.util.Date().getTime() );
java.sql.Date tomorrow= new java.sql.Date( now.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: perfect :) and short

Comment: This might not work in certain timezones, for example if you are in CET timezone, try using this for 30-10-2021

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the home page of **[Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)**:

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

1. Convert `java.sql.Date` object to `OffsetDateTime`.
2. Process the obtained `OffsetDateTime` to get the `OffsetDateTime` (or `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` as per the type of your database field) with the required values.
3. Use the value obtained from Step#2 directly with JDBC 4.2+. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

**Demo of the first two steps:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample data for demo - you already have this object
        java.sql.Date javaSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(1234567890123L);
        
        OffsetDateTime odtFromJavaSqlDate = new java.util.Date(javaSqlDate.getTime()).toInstant()
                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        
        OffsetDateTime odt = odtFromJavaSqlDate.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // If required, convert it to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // If required, convert it to LocalDate
        LocalDate date = odt.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2009-02-14T00:00Z
2009-02-14T00:00
2009-02-14
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DpEFb7)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
java.sql.Date result = new java.sql.Date(java.sql.Date.from(odt.toInstant()).getTime());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not the nicest way, but IMHO it's relatively easy to understand.
It creates a new midnight java.sql.Date object for the input date "now"

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    //create a date sql.Date object
    java.sql.Date now = new java.sql.Date( new java.util.Date().getTime() );

    //create a date formatter
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    //get the midnight date by converting the object to a String and back to a Date object
    java.util.Date midnightUtil = sf.parse( sf.format( now ) );
    //create a new java.sql.Date object and add one days worth of milliseconds;
    java.sql.Date midnight = new java.sql.Date( midnightUtil.getTime() + 86400000 );
```