# Entering a Date value in Postgresql with Java

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jdbc

I am trying to program a database application with java & PostgreSQL. I have some rows with date data type. But i cant add any entries to the database with this code :

```
Date aDate = null;
aDate.setYear(1990);
aDate.setDate(01);
aDate.setMonth(05);

preparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement("insert 
into exampletable values (?,?);");
prep.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) aDate);
prep.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) aDate);
```

How can i add a date in a postgreSQL row with queries in java?

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear whether or not this is your only problem, but this code is almost certainly not what you want:

```
Date aDate = null;
aDate.setYear(1990);
aDate.setDate(01);
aDate.setMonth(05);
```

- It will throw a `NullPointerException` because you're trying to dereference `null`
- You're then trying to set the year to 3890AD (`java.util.Date` is 1900-based for years)
- You're then setting the month to June. If you thought you were setting the month to May, think again - `Date` is 0-based for months
- All the methods you're using are deprecated - that should raise a big warning light for you
- You're then trying to cast `aDate` to `java.sql.Date` but there's no sign that it *is* a `java.sql.Date`

I would suggest:

- Either use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a far better date/time API, or `java.util.Calendar`
- Make sure you actually create an instance before you set values
- Probably create a new `java.sql.Date` later on.

For example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1990);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4); // Assuming you wanted May 1st

java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

// Ideally specify the columns here as well...
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(
    "insert into exampletable values (?,?)");
prep.setDate(1, date);
prep.setDate(2, date);
```

Comment: @RafaelWerlang: Your edit suggestion is incorrect. `Calendar.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date`; `java.util.Date.getTime()` returns a `long`. There's a `java.sql.Date(long)` constructor, but no `java.sql.Date(java.util.Date)` constructor.