# Convert into database date in java

Tags: java

I want to convert user entered date 31-12-2012 into PostgreSQL date format. i am appending date 'day-month-year' (31-12-2012)

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the database part of it - you shouldn't be providing it to the database as a string anyway.

Instead, use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the right pattern ("dd-MM-yyyy") to parse it into a `Date` (making sure you use the right time zone, which will be important later). Then to use this in a SQL statement, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and call [`setDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29). You'll need to create a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) from the [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) that you get out of `SimpleDateFormat.parse` though.

The time zone part is slightly messy - the documentation for `java.sql.Date` *suggests* that the JVM's default time zone is used to interpret a "millis since the epoch" value as a date. That would suggest you should use the default time zone when parsing, too - but it's far from elegant :(

Comment: I was taking look to other of your answers... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7662674/980472 I think it can be helpful here

Comment: @jddsantaella: I don't think so, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. I think you dint even try to google. Anyway, here is a sample code.

```
String User_date = "31-12-2012";
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(User_date);
```

This shall solve your problem.