# using the date type in java

Tags: java, date, resultset

I am trying to get two dates from a SQL query, and compare them.  So to compare them, I believe I will need to use the "Date" type.   Here is what I am trying, I know I am getting the date from the resultSet incorrectly, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
Date validDate = new Date(0);
Date currentDate = new Date(0);

// query

    if (result.next()) {

    validDate  = (result.getObject("validDate")!=null)?result.getObject("validDate").toDate():"";
    currentDate = (result.getObject("currentDate")!=null)?result.getObject("currentDate").toDate():"";
}

if (currentDate > validDate) {
    //do something
}
```

So again, this was my attempt, but I cant seem to get it to run.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:   the query has TO_CHAR(*column*, 'MM-DD-YYYY') on the two dates that I am getting.

Comment: Can you show us where you get "result"? Also, maybe an example of what a result.getObject("validDate") looks like.

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the modern Date-Time API. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Now you've mentioned that your query converts the date to a string, *stop doing that*. You'll end up reparsing it on the calling side - so why perform two conversions pointlessly? Keep string conversions to the absolute minimum - stay in the most appropriate data type wherever possible.

---

**Original answer**

You haven't shown what `result` is, but you probably want something like [`ResultSet.getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) to fetch the date values.

Note that your *comparison* code won't work either because there's no `>` for `Date` - you'd need something like:

```
if (currentDate.after(validDate))
```

Or fetch the underlying number of millis:

```
if (currentDate.getTime() > validDate.getTime())
```

Additionally:

- You can't assign "" to a `Date` variable - a string isn't a `Date`.
- You can just call `ResultSet.getDate()` and check whether the returned value is `null`, rather than calling `getObject` first and *then* `getDate()`

Answer (score 1):

Try   currentDate.after(validDate)

Answer (score 1):

To compdare dates I always use the before and after methodes of Date.

Answer (score 1):

Some nasty things can happen when accessing dates via the getObject method. You should try to use the `rs.getTimestamp` (with timeinfo) or the `rs.getDate` (without timeinfo) methods.

Also, because of the rather complex hierarchy of Date-objects you should compare Dates only using the `date1.compareTo(date2) > 0` method.

Answer (score 1):

if your result object is ResultSet, then

```
Date validDate = result.getTimestamp("validDate"); 
Date currentDate= result.getTimestamp("currentDate"); 
// you can add null checks here too....
// you can also use if (currentDate.getTime() > validDate.getTime()){}
if (currentDate.before(validDate)) { 
 //some code inhere...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three things wrong with your code:

- `""` is a `String` literal, so you cannot use it int your ternary expressions to be assigned to a variable of type `Date` - use `null` instead so you don't need a ternary
- `ResultSet.getObject()` returns an `Object`, which does not have a `toDate()` method. Instead, simply use `ResultSet.getDate()`
- You cannot compare `Date` instances using a `>` operator. You have to use the `before()` and `after()` methods of the `Date` class

Taking all this together, the following code might work:

```
Date validDate = new Date(0);
Date currentDate = new Date(0);

if (result.next()) {
    validDate  = result.getDate("validDate");
    currentDate = result.getDate("currentDate");
}
if (currentDate.after(validDate)) {
    //do something
}
```

The `if` clause may have to include some extra logic to deal with `null` values though. It's better to do that than to leave that to implicit conversions, too.