# converting a String to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date

I have a String as

```
strikedate="2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00"
```

I need to put this into a java.util.Date 
Could anybody please tell me how to convert this String to Date

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure - use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
Date parsed = sdf.parse(text);
```

EDIT: Eek - it's not quite that simple, due to your time zone format. The above will work *without* the colon. You may need to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to parse the version *with* the colon. Checking that now...

EDIT: Yes, with Joda Time you can use:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime parsed = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
// If you really need it
Date date = parsed.toDate();
```

Joda Time is also a much nicer date/time API to start with - I'd strongly encourage you to use it if you can.

Comment: `String dateStr = "2013-06-25T16:09:41.276-05:00";`
`Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}-)(\\d{2}:\\d{2})").matcher(dateStr);`  
`if (m.matches()) {`  
`    dateStr = m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace(":", "");`  
`}`  
`Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(dateStr);`
`System.out.printf("Date = '%s'", date);`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (namely, its inherited `parse()` method).
The format string should be "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" - though that expectes the zimezone to come without a colon, so you may have to preprocess the string to remove the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
offset = "GMT-04:00";
String date = "2010-10-12T20:01:18.000Z";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
str = sdf.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-11-19T00:00-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qU0PIz)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use the modern Date-Time API with JDBC.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Solution using the legacy API:

For the sake of completeness, given below is the solution using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00");

        // Display date in UTC/GMT
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

        // Display date in the timezone with an offset of -05:00 hours
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-11-19T05:00:00.000Z
2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/D5WsVx)

Note that a `java.util.Date` object does not hold any format and timezone information, it applies the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` and the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString` derived from this milliseconds value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>