# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

Tags: java

Could anybody please tell me why i am getting `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date` in the following code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class Testdate {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String text = "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        try {
            Date parsed = sdf.parse(text.trim());
            System.out.println(parsed);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because of the colon in your timezone. Remove it and it will work:

```
String text = "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-0500";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: you used a different String , but the actual String is "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-05:00";   , I want the colon also

Comment: was just the explanation why it fails, and one way how to work around it.

Comment: I would investigate why you get a date, which is not RFC conform.. you can workaround it by just removing the last colon, but this is obviously a bad work around.

Comment: Here's how I removed the colon:

    String dateStr = "2013-06-25T16:09:41.276-05:00";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}-)(\\d{2}:\\d{2})").matcher(dateStr);
    if (m.matches()) {
        dateStr = m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace(":", "");
    }
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(dateStr);
    System.out.printf("Date = '%s'", date);

Answer (score 5):

Because the `Z` part of `SimpleDateFormat`'s pattern support doesn't handle offsets with colons in.

I suggest you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, using `ISODateFormat.dateTime()` to get an appropriate formatter.

(See this [similar-but-not-quite-the-same-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151067/converting-a-string-to-java-util-date/8151120#8151120) from earlier today for more information.)