# Getting wrong month when using SimpleDateFormat.parse

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

In my programm there is a very strange problem. Here you can see `String birthday` and `Log` to check it:

```
birthday = String.valueOf(birthYear) + "-" + String.valueOf(birthMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(birthDay);
Log.i(TAG, "Birthday: " + birthday)
```

Then I put it to SimpleDateFormat and check it with the `Log`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

Date birthDate = sdf.parse(birthday);
Log.i(TAG, "Birth date  : " + birthDate);
```

And then in `Logcat` I have:

```
I/App﹕ Birthday: 1999-10-15
I/App﹕ Birth date: Fri Jan 15 00:10:00 GMT+04:00 1999
```

So as you see in the date it is `Jan`, but in the String it is `10` so date should look like:

```
Fri Nov 15 00:10:00 GMT+04:00 1999
```

Where is my mistake?

P.S I think my question is somehow connected with [Getting wrong data when using SimpleDateFormat.parse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831950/getting-wrong-data-when-using-simpledateformat-parse)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Use `MM` for **month**, `mm` for **minutes** as stated by [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...

If you want to print a `Date` in a specific format, you should use:

```
 sdf.format(birthday)
```

or another `SimpleDateFormat` if you want to pring it in a different format...

Comment: Now it is `Fri Oct 15 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 1999`

Comment: Why `Oct`? I think there should be `Nov`?

Comment: Why do you think it should be November? October is the 10th month.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and I found the error now. We should use `MM` for month, `mm` for minutes and `dd` for day. Using `DD` changed my date to wrong month, so I used `dd` for day and so final format I used is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

### ThreeTenABP

I should like to provide the 2017 answer. For Android, first get the ThreeTenABP library. Instructions are in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Then the rest is as straightforward as:

```
    LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
    System.out.println("Birth date  : " + birthDate);
```

This prints:

```
Birth date  : 1999-10-15
```

When you’ve got the year, month and day of month as numbers, there is no need to do any parsing, that would just complicate things.

ThreeTenABP is the backport of `java.time` or JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API, to Android Java 7. If you are using Java 8 or later, `java.time` is built-in. There is also a backport for (non-Android) Java 6 and 7: [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).