# Localdate.format, format is not applied

Tags: java, date, javafx, datepicker, fxml

I have a DatePicker in my FXML and I need the Date to insert it into my SQL-Database. I want to format my Date but it doesn't work.

```
    LocalDate localDate = purchased_at.getValue();
    localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.mm.yyyy"));
```

This is the Error I get.

```
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: MinuteOfHour
```

I'm still kind of a beginner. I had Java for the past 3 or 4 months now. I'm trying my best to improve.

Comment: `mm` probably refers to `minutes`, instead of `months`. You should check the documentation.

Comment: You should be using `MM` instead of `mm`.

Comment: You also need to pick up the format from the return value from `localDate.format()`. The `LocalDate` itself is immutable and not altered by the call.

Comment: I tried it out with MM instead of mm. Still doesn't work. I also tried it with localDate.format() but IntelliJ tells me format (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)in LocalDate cannot be applied to String

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing) and of [Getting wrong month when using SimpleDateFormat.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141942/getting-wrong-month-when-using-simpledateformat-parse). Also akin to [String to ZonedDateTime is changing format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120213/string-to-zoneddatetime-is-changing-format).

Comment: `LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));` work, so changing the format specifier from `mm` to `MM` should be the way to go

Comment: Don’t format your date for insertion into your database. Just pass it as it is. Your JDBC driver or JPA implementation will take care of everything.

Comment: @whoever voted to close, the issues in the question are non-trivial and IMHO also interesting to other readers. The exception reported is readily reproducible always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a String converter for my Datepicker.

```
    public String changeformat(DatePicker date) {

    date.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
        String pattern = "MM.yyyy";
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

        {
            date.setPromptText(pattern.toLowerCase());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDate date) {
            if (date != null) {
                return dateFormatter.format(date);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
            if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
                return LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

It worked perfectly fine. I had to use a parameter since I'm currently using 5 Datepickers.

Answer (score 7):

Don’t format your date for insertion into your SQL database. Assuming that your database column has datatype `date` and you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, just pass the `LocalDate` to your `PreparedStatement` as it is:

```
    PreparedStatement insertStmt = myConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into my_table(purchase_date) values (?)");
    insertStmt.setObject(1, purchaseDate);
```

Your JDBC driver will take care of the rest. If using JPA, your JPA implementation will take care of it too.

If your column has char type (for example `varchar(10)`) and you cannot change it, don’t invent your own format for it. Store the date in ISO 8601 format. `LocalDate.toString()` produces this format.

```
    String formattedDate = purchaseDate.toString();
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

In my case output was:

> 2017-11-29

As an aside, for presentation to your user you shouldn’t invent your own format either. Rather rely on the built-in formats in Java. For example:

```
    Locale turkish = Locale.forLanguageTag("tr");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(turkish);
    String formattedDate = purchaseDate.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output:

> 29.11.2017

### What went wrong in your code?

There are two things wrong:

1. You used lowercase `mm`. This means minute of hour, and since a `LocalDate` doesn’t have a time of day in it, it threw the exception you saw. The message you got is pretty precise:

> Unsupported field: MinuteOfHour

Instead you may use uppercase `MM` for two-digit month.

2. You need to pick up the format in the `String` returned from the `format` method. The `LocalDate` is immutable and therefore not affected by the method call. Also it cannot have a format in it. It’s just a date in the calendar.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)
- [How to format LocalDate object to MM/dd/yyyy and have format persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689866/how-to-format-localdate-object-to-mm-dd-yyyy-and-have-format-persist) (TL;DR: you cannot)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Is there any possible way to insert a date only with the month and the year (05.2018) instead of the full date (22.05.2018)

Comment: If the datatype in the database is `date`, it will probably insist on storing a day of month too. You would need to check this with the documentation of the RDBMS. Are you using MySQL?