# How to get a month as an integer from the given date and print as month name format ("MMM")

Tags: java, calendar, date-formatting, date-parsing

I am new to Java and couldnt retrieve the month while using the below code instead month value is set to 0. Please advise the mistakes that i have done here.

*

```
for(int i=0;i<this.input.size();i++)
     {
         SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

         Date purchasedate;
        try {
            String details  = input.get(i);
            String[] detailsarr = details.split(",");
            purchasedate = sf.parse(detailsarr[1]);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(purchasedate);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

*
After getting the above month as an integer, Could you please advise if there is anyway to print the above month value as "MMM" format?

Comment: First, the classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` are long outdated and were always poorly designed. `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is renowned for trouble, Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s so much nicer to work with. So I recommend you upgrade to java.time and forget about the old classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing). Or possibly more clearly a duplicate of [Getting wrong month when using SimpleDateFormat.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141942/getting-wrong-month-when-using-simpledateformat-parse).

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. At first glance, your links do not seem to be spot-on originals. But I appreciate the effort you made. I am sure this is a duplicate though I could not quickly find an exact original.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(          // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    "23/01/2018" ,        // Tip: Use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than this localized format for data-exchange of date-time values.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
)                         // Return a `LocalDate` object.
.getMonth()               // Return a `Month` enum object representing the month of this date.
.getDisplayName(          // Automatically localize, generating text of the name of this month.
    TextStyle.SHORT ,     // Specify (a) how long or abbreviated, and (b) specify whether used in stand-alone or combo context linguistically (irrelevant in English). 
    Locale.US             // Specify the human language and cultural norms to use in translation.
)                         // Returns a `String`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/plGIox).

> Jan

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` classes.

### ISO 8601

Tip: When exchanging date-time values as text, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats rather than using text meant for presentation to humans. For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD such as 2018-01-23.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2018" , f ) ;
```

### `Month` enum

Retrieve the month as a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
Month m = ld.getMonth() ;
```

### Localize

Ask that `Month` enum to generate a `String` with text of the name of the month. The `getDisplayName` method can automatically localize for you. To localize, specify:

- [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be. Note that in some languages you may need to choose stand-alone style depending on context in which you intend to use the result.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Code:

```
String output = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.US ) ;
```

### Use enum, not integer

Notice that we had no use of an integer number to represent the month. Using an enum object instead makes our code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides [type-safety](http://hhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

So I strongly recommend passing around `Month` objects rather than mere `int` integer numbers. But if you insist, call [`Month.getMonthValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonthValue()) to get a number. The numbering is sane, 1-12 for January-December, unlike the legacy classes.

```
int monthNumber = ld.getMonthValue() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");

    String dateStringFromInput = "29/08/2018";
    LocalDate purchasedate = LocalDate.parse(dateStringFromInput, dateFormatter);

    int monthNumber = purchasedate.getMonthValue();
    System.out.println("Month number is " + monthNumber);
```

Running the above snippet gives this output:

> Month number is 8

Note that contrary to `Calendar` `LocalDate` numbers the months the same way humans do, August is month 8. However to get the month formatted into a standard three letter abbreviation we don’t need the number first:

```
    Locale irish = Locale.forLanguageTag("ga");
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", irish);

    String formattedMonth = purchasedate.format(monthFormatter);
    System.out.println("Formatted month: " + formattedMonth);
```

> Formatted month: Lún

Please supply your desired locale where I put Irish/Gaelic. Java knows the month abbreviations in a vast number of languages.

### What went wrong in your code?

Apart from using the long outdated date and time classes, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`, format pattern letters are case sensitive (this is true with the modern `DateTimeFormatter` too). To parse or format a month you need to use uppercase `M` (which you did correctly in your title). Lowercase `m` is for minute of the hour. `SimpleDateFormat` is troublesome here (as all too often): rather than telling you something is wrong through an exception it just tacitly defaults the month to January. Which `Calendar` in turn returns to you as month 0 because it unnaturally numbers the months from 0 through 11.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Question: Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of doing this is

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = cal.getTime();     
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

In your case modify snippet like below:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
 Date purchasedate;
 try {
        String details  = input.get(i);
        String[] detailsarr = details.split(",");
        purchasedate = sf.parse(detailsarr[1]);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        String month = sdf.format(purchasedate);
   }
```

Comment: Repeating the bug that caused the asker’s code to give 0 always — now it just gives `Jan`, always, depending on locale. It’s not your fault. It’s primarily because `SimpleDateFormat` is troublesome and doesn’t help you detect the error.