# Get only the date from the timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp

This is my Below function in which I am passing timestamp, I need only the date in return from the timestamp not the Hours and Second. With the below code I am getting-

```
private String toDate(long timestamp) {
        Date date = new Date (timestamp * 1000);
        return DateFormat.getInstance().format(date).toString();
}
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
11/4/01 11:27 PM
```

But I need only the date like this

```
2001-11-04
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use  `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` . Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZoneId, ``ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat instead:

```
private String toDate(long timestamp) {
    Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
}
```

*Updated*: Java 8 solution:

```
private String toDate(long timestamp) {
    LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp * 1000).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks s106mo for the answer. One more doubt I have, is there any way I can get the yesterday's date always with the same function I wrote above? As this is my second requirement.

Comment: Did I get you right: the `toDate` method should give you the date of yesterday based on the current timestamp? Then you could calculate the date of yesterday in this fashin: `Date date = new Date(timestamp - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));`

Comment: In order to retrieve the time info as well below can be used:
 LocalDateTime date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp * 1000L).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        try{
            return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"));
        }

Comment: Rather than brewing your own formatter you will probably prefer to use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to get the required results

```
protected Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());


protected String today_Date=timestamp.toString().split(" ")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

You can use [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) to get an `Instant` out of the given `timestamp` and then use [`LocalDate.ofInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) to get a `LocalDate` out of the obtained `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(toDate(1636120105L));
    }

    static LocalDate toDate(long timestamp) {
        return LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-11-05
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/P350dp)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: About time (read overdue) that there’s a pure java.time answer to this often-visited question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is where the introduction of `LocalDate.ofInstant()` (in Java 9) is really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class to represent a date-only value without any time-of-day nor time zone.

### Time Zone

Determining a date requires a [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). A moment just after midnight in Paris means a date that is a day ahead of the same simultaneous moment in Montréal. If you neglect to specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied – probably not what you want as results may vary.

### Example Code

```
long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = ( yourNumberOfSecondsSinceUnixEpoch * 1000 ); // Convert seconds to milliseconds.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch, timeZone );
String output = localDate.toString(); // Defaults to ISO 8601 standard format, YYYY-MM-DD.
```

### Previous Day

To get the day before, as requested in a comment.

```
LocalDate dayBefore = localDate.minusDays( 1 );
```

### Convert to j.u.Date

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes **should be avoided** as they are notoriously troublesome. But if required, you may convert.

```
java.util.Date date = localDate.toDate(); // Time-of-day set to earliest valid for that date.
```