# How to get date only in java.utill object in android

Tags: xamarin.android

Hello i want date without time but that should  be in java.utill object

output should be - 2014-08-22

Comment: What you try till now boss. Can you put some code what u tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only the date from the timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421527/get-only-the-date-from-the-timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date holds internally the date/time as a long (milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). What you see when you are doing

```
Systeme.err.println(new Date());
```

is the result of the toString() method of Date class.

For further formatting read the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date();
    int day = date.getDate();
    String Day;
    int month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    String Month;
    int year = date.getYear() + 1900;
    String Year = Integer.toString(year);
    if (day < 10) {
        Day = "0" + Integer.toString(day);
    } else {
        Day = Integer.toString(day);
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        Month = "0" + Integer.toString(month);
    } else {
        Month = Integer.toString(month);
    }
    String dates = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day;
    System.out.println(dates);
```

Comment: i want output in date not in string

Comment: i dont think you can do it just create a new object

Comment: You may want to explain what your code is doing here too.  Code dumping is usually discouraged here on StackOverflow.