# Retrieve date from SQLite and set it into TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have date in sqlite but in timestamp format, I want to set that date into a text view but in actual date format any idea?

This saved my date in sqlite in timestamp format:

```
void insertNewTask(String task, String date)
{
 SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("TaskName",task);
 values.put("dateStr", getDate(date));
 db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
 db.close();
}
```

and now I want to get date in actual format and set it into text-view:

```
ArrayList<String> getTaskList()
{
 ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE,new String[]{"TaskName","dateStr"},null,null,null,null,null);
 while(cursor.moveToNext()){
 int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("TaskName");
 taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
}
 cursor.close();
 db.close();
 return taskList;
}
```

I have this getDate() Method:

```
private long getDate(String day) 
{
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
 Date date = new Date();
 try 
{
  date = dateFormat.parse(day);
}
 catch (ParseException e) {}
 return date.getTime(); //I have used this method in insertNewTask()
}
```

Comment: where is the exception ?

Comment: No exceptions but I  want to retrieve date from database in normal date format.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421527/get-only-the-date-from-the-timestamp/11421638]`private String toDate(long timestamp) {
    Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
}`

Comment: Actually I wanna create todo app with task and date entered by the user  am very confused any help?