# How parse 2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000 date string to Date

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime-format

How to parse this format date string **2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000** to Date object?

I'm trying on this way but it doesn't work.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD");
Date result =  df.parse(time);
```

I get this exception from the first line:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`,  `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69715173/5772882).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");`

Year is lower case y.
Any characters that are in the input which are not related to the date (like the 'T' in `2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000` should be quoted in `''`.

For a list of the defined pattern letters see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Parse checks that the given date is in the format you specified.
To print the date in a specific format after checking see below:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
Date result;
try {
    result = df.parse("2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000");
    System.out.println("date:"+result); //prints date in current locale
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(result)); //prints date in the format sdf
}
```

Comment: @HarisDautović are you using the correct ' to surround the T ? this is Alt+39 not some other apostrophe like `

Comment: Date.toString() uses the local time zone, println is using toString() so you get the local time zone.

Comment: @msam, in your answer you mentioned «*Any characters that are in the input which are not related to the date should be quoted in `''`*». But at the same time `Z` in your initial example was not surrounded by «`''`», is it OK? I just added `'Z'` and everything is working now.

Comment: @MikeB. Z is part of the Date - it's the Timezone in the +0000 format. 'Z' would mean that the string to parse has a "Z" character

Comment: @msam, It's strange, in my case `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH); LocalDateTime maxDate = pubDates.stream().map(s -> LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)).max(LocalDateTime::compareTo).get();` works only if I surround `Z` with `''`.

Comment: @MikeB. are you sure the string that is being parsed is in the specified format? `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH); 
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000",formatter);` works - surrounding Z with '' throws an exception.

Comment: In my case the date is in this format: `2016-02-12T09:19:00Z`.

Comment: @MikeB. If you have a 'Z' character then it must quoted as you said. Unquoted Z refers to the time zone (+ or - followed by 4 digits)

Comment: for me removein tick from z helped 'Z'

Answer (score 58):

Try:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

in specific:

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: try DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

Comment: what about "2020-03-30T07:37:02.282+01:00"

Comment: @user3475052 yyyy-MM-dd’T’hh:mm:ss.SSSZ

Answer (score 8):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Your input string has timezone offset and therefore it should be parsed to `OffsetDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxx", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000", dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-03-13T20:59:31Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gZDQLu)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

#### If at all you need `java.util.Date`:

You can use [`Date#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) to get an instance of `java.util.Date`, as shown below:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: About time (read: overdue) this frequently viewed question got a current (non-outdated) answer! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

For **2017-02-08 06:23:35 +0000** this kind of Date format, i use below format:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate;
formatDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ");
```

Its working for me. Other answers not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate;
formatDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-05-08T11:12:13+0001", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
```

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and its `ZonedDateTime` class. A `ZonedDateTime` is a date and time with a time zone. If you want to use java.time before Android Oreo (API level 26), you need [core library desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

I am enclosing `T` in single quotes so the formatter knows that it is not a pattern letter. The `T` without quotes in the question was the reason for your exception, but there were other problems in the format patterns string too. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code -only answers are discouraged. It's helpful to describe how this answer addresses the 8-year-old question that's different from the other existing answers.

Comment: Will you explain more about the details regarding the answer. Make it more meaning full and clear.

Answer (score 2):

it can help also

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
```