# ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime() cannot parse 2015-11-18T00:00:00+0000

Tags: java, jodatime

I have string in this format "2015-11-18T00:00:00+0000". I thought it's a ISO8601 format and tried to parse it to a Joda `DateTime` instance, but it told me it's malformed:

```
String toParse = "2015-11-18T00:00:00+0000";
DateTime date = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(toParse);
```

And I got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-11-18T00:00:00+0000" is malformed at "+0000"

How can I convert the above string to a `DateTime`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How parse 2013-03-13T20:59:31+0000 date string to Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433377/how-parse-2013-03-13t2059310000-date-string-to-date)

Comment: @Malkus Not a duplicate, at least not related to the link you have given. It is a Joda-specific problem, see my answer.

Comment: @Malkus by no way this is a duplicate, it's about different framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()` requires a millisecond part which is missing in your input. Solution: Use the method [dateTimeNoMillis()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis--).

```
String input = "2015-11-18T00:00:00+0000";
DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(input);
System.out.println(dt); // 2015-11-18T01:00:00.000+01:00 (using offset of default timezone)
```

If you want to preserve the offset (+0000) contained in your input then you will also need to call `withOffsetParsed()` on your formatter.