# How to convert "2019-08-07T14:00:00-0400" to SQL DATETIME format in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-parsing

I couldn't pass in `2019-08-07T14:00:00-0400` to a stored procedure in SQL Server that takes a param in `DATETIME`.

So how can I convert it to this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS` in Java prior to calling the stored procedure?

Comment: If you want to convert it in Java then why tag SQL Server?

Comment: `I couldn't pass ...` What have you tried to do? Are you trying to pass a string? What happened? Seeing the actual code will help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I think it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433377/how-parse-2013-03-13t2059310000-date-string-to-date). Please try this.

Comment: I'm trying to pass in a string `2019-08-07T14:00:00-0400` in Java to a stored proc, and convert that to 121 style. I tagged sql server because I'm open to both java solution and sql solution.

Comment: Don't pass datetime values as Strings. Use a [PreparedStatement](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) and pass them as instances of `LocalDateTime`

Comment: `-0400` in your string is a timezone offset. Can `datetime` in SQL Server include it? Or does it always assume UTC, for example? Your desired format, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`,  seems to indicate that you will be losing this crucial piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `SimpleDateFormat`class for reference visit [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
Date date = df.parse("2019-08-07T14:00:00-0400");
```

You will get `java.util.Date` object in return which in turns you can use to store in database.

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` - you should **at least** use `java.sql.Timestamp` but `java.time.LocalDateTime` would be the preferred solution.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. can you share your thoughts and suggest a better solution for specified format?

Comment: I would like to write an answer in line with the comment by @a_horse_with_no_name using a datetime object such as `LocalDateTime` rather than a string; but I don’t know SQL Server and its JDBC driver well enough to be sure that `LocalDateTime` is the exact correct Java type (it does sound correct). So I won’t.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it in SQL queries you can use below query.

```
 declare @abc nvarchar(19)='2019-08-07T14:00:00-0400'
 select CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(varchar, @abc,121))
```

Comment: In SQL Server, *never* use `char`, `varchar` and so on without  lengths!  The defaults vary by context and can lead to unexpected and very hard-to-debug errors.