# java Instant and MS SQL datetimeoffset

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime

I'm using spring, mybatis, mssql-jdbc-8.4.1...

I have quite simple test code to save and fetch model from DB.
Model field is of type Instant, DB column is of type datetimeoffset.

After persisting / fetching I have time difference exactly on my timezone offset.
Changing DB column type to datetime2 fixes the problem.

**Q:** Should I treat this as underlying libraries issues (either mybatis or jbdc driver) or I have wrong expectation of java Instant being saved in UTC timezone and fetched as such to remain valid 'instant'?

Answer (score 4):

> Changing DB column type to datetime2 fixes the problem.

`datetime2` is MS SQL Server type corresponding to ANSI SQL `TIMESTAMP` type and it maps to `LocalDateTime` in JDBC 4.2. A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) does not hold any timezone information and therefore you will get the same value always.

If you want to store it in such a way that the retrieved value should change automatically in a timezone with a different offset value, you should save it to a database field of type, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` which corresponds to `OffsetDateTime`. Note that most JDBC drivers do not support `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. Also, most of these drivers require the `OffsetDateTime` instances to be with a timezone offset of `+00:00` hours because the backend stores them as UTC.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) for some more information.