# Java variable is Timestamp on one machine and LocalDateTime on another

Tags: java, tomcat, localdatetime

I have a Java application, when I debug it on one machine, the type of a variable is LocalDateTime, but on another machine it is Timestamp.

This is the actual variable

```
Object teste = rs.getObject(i);
```

This is the LocalDateTime one, the Apache version is 7.0.106 and it is running with Windows Server 2019

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.109
Server built:   Apr 22 2021 18:43:38 UTC
Server number:  7.0.109.0
OS Name:        Windows Server 2019
OS Version:     10.0
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_291-b10
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

This is on the Timestamp one, the Apache version is 7.0.109 and it is running with Windows 10

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.106
Server built:   Sep 16 2020 08:33:41 UTC
Server number:  7.0.106.0
OS Name:        Windows 10
OS Version:     10.0
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_271-b09
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

I don't think it has something to do with the version, since it is just a patch, and reading the changelog there is nothing about it, I think it can be some configuration, but I can't find anything, if anyone could give me a guide or a place to look at, I would appreciate.

Comment: What happens when you try with the same JDK versions? Since you are reading from a result set, are the database drivers/versions the same?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask]. Some actual code would also show us how you actually retrieve your object.

Comment: Another question is how you construct the .jar. You could include all dependencies to exclude some library issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: And of course, we need to see the source code and possibly (parts of) your pom.xml - if on Maven. Include more of your source code. What is rs ?

Comment: Hi, I have done something similar as a workaround, I checked if the type of the variable was LocalDateTime and converted it to TImestamp, but thanks for your time and answer, I am sure it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JDBC driver allows, specify that you want `LocalDateTime` each time:

```
LocalDateTime teste = rs.getObject(i, LocalDateTime.class);
```

`LocalDateTime` and other java.time classes are supported in this way since JDBC 4.2.

Even better, assuming that your timestamp is just that, defining a point in time, use `OffsetDateTime`, not `LocalDateTime`. In most SQL databases you will then need to use `timestamp with time zone`.

**Alternatives for old JDBC drivers**

If specifying a java.time class to `getObject()` breaks, preferably upgrade your JDBC driver to one where it works. If for some reason you cannot do that, retrieve an old-fashioned `Timestamp` and convert it.

```
LocalDateTime teste = rs.getTimestamp(i).toLocalDateTime();
```

Or better for defining a point in time:

```
Instant teste = rs.getTimestamp(i).toInstant();
```

**Why was the behaviour different?**

Probably you had different versions of your JDBC driver installed on those two computers. This can explain why one returns an old-fashioned `Timestamp` and the other a modern `LocalDateTime`. `ResultSet` and its methods including `getObject` are implemented in the driver.

**Link**

[Arvind Kumar Avinash’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882) to *[Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285553/dates-with-no-time-or-timezone-component-in-java-mysql)*. It’s a different question, but that answer contains much good information that I think will be useful for you too.