# How to add a datetime Into my SQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc

Currently, I am trying to add my datetime into SQL from JavaFX GUI, but I keep getting the number format exception error. The Datetime format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, but I can also add in just like 12:30 etc.

```
private void doAdd() {
    //Input from the user in GUI format
    int EntryID = Integer.valueOf(tfEntryID.getText());
    String PersonName = tfPersonName.getText();
    int CheckInTime = Integer.parseInt(tfCheckInTime.getText());
    String CheckTime = String.valueOf(CheckInTime);
    Date date = new Date(CheckInTime);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ;
    String currentDateTime = format.format(date);
    String insertSql = String.format("INSERT INTO entry_records(
        EntryID, PersonName, CheckTime) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %s)",
        EntryID , PersonName ,currentDateTime );
    int rowsAdded = DBUtil.execSQL(insertSql);
    if (rowsAdded == 1) {
        System.out.println("STATUS: ADD Entry Record (ID" + EntryID + ") Successful!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Adding failed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple things: **(1)** I suggest avoiding the old date&time classes (e.g. `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`) if at all possible, and instead use the "new" `java.time` API added in Java 8 (e.g. `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`, etc.); **(2)** _Never_ create your SQL queries like you're currently doing; it's unsafe, the worst being the potential for SQL injection—intentional or not. Use a `PreparedStatement` and use its API to set the needed parameters.

Comment: Then you have at least two things to research: **(1)** How to use data-time objects with JDBC, and **(2)** how to parse a date-time with optional parts.

Comment: Related: [Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285553/dates-with-no-time-or-timezone-component-in-java-mysql)

Comment: The `NumberFormatException` probably comes from either `Integer.valueOf(tfEntryID.getText())` or `Integer.parseInt(tfCheckInTime.getText())`. Your stack trace should tell you which of those two lines. So please also tell us: (1) What text is in those text fields? (2) Which line does the stack trace refer to? (3) What is the full exception message (please paste it into your question)?

Answer (score 7):

Never use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They are terribly flawed in design. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can exchange date-time objects with your database use *java.time* objects. No need for string manipulations.

Parse your input string into a `LocalDateTime` object if you have only date and time-of-day and intend to ignore time zones.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( … ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Write that value to your database using a `PreparedStatement` to avoid the security risks of [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

The `LocalDateTime` class is appropriate to a database column of a type akin to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. These types are inherently ambiguous as they both purposely lack the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So they cannot represent a moment, are not a specific point on the timeline.

To represent a moment, use classes `Instant`/`OffsetDateTime`/`ZonedDateTime`, with `OffsetDateTime` being appropriate to SQL exchange. For database column type, use a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

---

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Very good answer. Peter, there’s important information in this paragraph: *To represent a moment, use …* Please read twice, at least. For the sake of your users.