# How to convert string date into timestamp

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, datetime-format

We are getting a date from an API in string and the format is `RFC3339`. I need to convert this into a timestamp in this format `20-MAR-22 12.00.00.00.000000000 AM`

I tried using `Timestamp.valueOf(objUs.getUserAcptDate)` but here we are getting an exception.

I found by searching online RFC3339 is in this formate `"2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z"` or it may be without `T`.

How can we convert the coming string from API into a timestamp and this is the formate which we are saving in DB `20-MAR-22 12.00.00.00.000000000 AM`

Comment: See `LocalDateTime`

Comment: *and this is the formate which we are saving in DB 20-MAR-22 12.00.00.00.000000000 AM* Your db column has a character type to hold a date? If so, it shouldn't.

Comment: @g00se Is correct and a bit more. I hope you are using a `timestamp`, best `with time zone` in your database. Since JDBC 4.2 you can and should pass java.time types to your database such as `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` or `LocalDateTime`. See for example [Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285553/dates-with-no-time-or-timezone-component-in-java-mysql). Hibernate will be fine with doing the same. So use no string for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse/format date-time objects. There are many [predefined formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) or you could build custom if required. For some advanced scenarios you could use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that provides many different options for parsing and formatting.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter CUSTOM_DATE = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.m.ss.n a");
private static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_DATE = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;


String input = "2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z";
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, ISO_DATE);
String output = CUSTOM_DATE.format(date);
```

Comment: That should work. Only `.n` for the decimal part in the format pattern string is dangerous. If the time has, say 23.01 seconds, they wil come out as 23.10000000 where you would have wanted 23.010000000. I suggest `.SSSSSSSSS` for the decimal part. You should also specify a locale for the formatter to make sure the month abbreviation will be in English.