# Converting UTC time to Date object

Tags: java, time, utc, java.util.date

I am trying to get the current UTC time and convert it into a Date object:

```
      OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
      Date date = Date.from(now.toInstant());
```

The problem I face is that `OffsetDateTime` returns the correct time, for example `2023-03-22T08:46:38.562331200Z`, which is correct in the time of writing, but when converting it to `Date` object the date
becomes `Wed Mar 22 10:46:38 EET 2023` with my timezone EET, how can I create a Date object with the UTC time  2023-03-22T08:46:38.562331200Z retrieved?

Comment: I am trying to convert it to Date so then I can pass it to a query in the database which expect Date object to compare with

Comment: I think yes , it returns the correct UTC time

Comment: Avoid the outdated `Date` class if you can. If you need one for a legacy API, just trust that you have got the right one even though it prints in your local time zone (`Date` objects always did that).

Comment: How are you querying the database? Most modern JDBC drivers accept an `OffsetDateTime` as query parameter. See for example [this answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882). As I said, don’t use `Date` if you can avoid it.

Comment: *but when converting it to Date object the date becomes Wed Mar 22 10:46:38 EET 2023 with my timezone EET* It doesn't. What you probably mean is this is what is getting printed when you visualize it. That's because your system timezone is being applied to it