# Get the Timestamp value from database as same as it is using java

Tags: java, mysql, date, timestamp, datetime-format

In a MySQL database table, there is column named ***loginTime*** and its type is ***timestamp***. Its value is ***2023-02-14 10:02:26***.

when I get the value to date type variable using java and I get value as ***2023-02-14 10:02***. How can I get the date with seconds also. As same as the database. I tried but still unable to find solution.

Comment: Retrieve into an `OffsetDateTime`. See for example [this good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882) (the question is about the opposite problem, but the answer does cover both. Since a MySQL `timestamp` is always in UTC, `OffsetDateTime` should be the right class to use in Java, but you may have to experiment a little.

Comment: *when I get the value to date type variable using java and I get value as 2023-02-14 10:02.* That shouldn't be happening. `java.sql.Date` shouldn't even give you *any* time. `rs.getTimestamp(0).toLocalDateTime()` is the sort of thing you need

Comment: @g00se That’s an improvement. It’s still better to avoid the `Timestamp` class completely: `rs.getObject(0, LocalDateTime.class)` (assuming JDBC 4.2 or later).

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh yes, I forgot, thanks.

Comment: @OleV.V. Your second comment using `LocalDateTime` contradicts your first comment using `OffsetDateTime`. (the first comment being the correct usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably need to include the timestamp class which allows the JDBC API to identify a java.util.Date object as an SQL TIMESTAMP value. Here we set a timestamp value to include fractional seconds and display this:

```
// old classes and approach in use here, read on for more 
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TimestampExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String timestampStr = "2023-02-14 10:02:26.123";
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
            Timestamp loginTime = new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(timestampStr).getTime());
            System.out.println("loginTime: " + loginTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Added: Here is an alternative using Java.time (see comments under answer)

```
// don't use this approach if the source data has embedded time zone information 
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimestampExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String timestampStr = "2023-02-14 10:02:26.123";
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            LocalDateTime loginTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampStr, formatter);
            System.out.println("loginTime: " + loginTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

There was never an intent to focus on handling date/time information as text, the snippets above were simply designed to easily visualize sub-second precision. Based on the rolling wave of advice from the comments I'll presume that something along the following lines will more correctly handle a MySQL "timestamp".

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class TimestampExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Assume the connection has been established

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT login_time FROM users WHERE id = 1");

            if (rs.next()) {
                OffsetDateTime loginTime = rs.getObject("login_time", OffsetDateTime.class);
                System.out.println("loginTime: " + loginTime);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*this variant is untested*

Comment: that's the point, if it comes as date the your loose precision, are you saying you cannot use the timestamp suggestion?

Comment: can you just use getString ? Maybe you should include a script snippet on how you get the data now (IN the QUESTION please, not here, use the Edit seen under the tags of your question).

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the poorly designed, troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and `Timestamp` classes. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and [JDBC 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882), which supports java.time types.

Comment: Thanks for extending the answer with the modern version of the code, which, as I said, is certainly recommended over the old one. Another point, retrieving a timestamp as a string from the database is the second best way at best. Prefer to retrieve a proper date-time object such as an `OffsetDateTime`, an `Instant` or if all else fails, then a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. The `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL is a date with time as seen in UTC. The `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of offset, so you are tragically discarding valuable information. I must down-vote for being incorrect.

Comment: third variant added to "answer" (which I am now unable to delete)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Correct modern solution:

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )  // Returns an `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object.
```

You said:

> column named loginTime and its type is timestamp. Its value is 2023-02-14 10:02:26.

**No, you are incorrect.** The `TIMESTAMP` type represents a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. Your reported value lacks the indication of an offset from UTC of zero, which is vital info.

## Details

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75820248/642706) is ill-advised in three ways:

- The first part uses terribly flawed legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).
- The second part employs the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class. `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. The `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL is a date with time as seen in UTC. The `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so that solution tragically discards valuable information. Note earlier [Comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820141/get-the-timestamp-value-from-database-as-same-as-it-is-using-java/75830568#comment133745229_75820141)
- Both parts focus on parsing text retrieved from the database. Instead, date-time column values should be retrieved into date-time types in Java. No need to resort to text.

First step is to read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) for the `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL 8.0. To quote:

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Those mentions of [“UTC”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) are vital. That term is an abbreviation meaning “with an offset from the temporal meridian of UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds”.

In [the SQL Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization_history), this type is equivalent to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (where the Standard authors incorrectly used the term “time zone” where they meant “offset”).

### `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

So the appropriate Java type mapped to such a column in the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2+ specification is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To write such a value to the database, pass your `OffsetDateTime` object to `PreparedStatement#setObject`.