# How to convert epoch to mySQL timestamp in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, epoch

How to get mySQL timestamp format in `mySQLtimestamp`?

```
long epochNow = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
long epochWeek = 604800;
long date7daysAgo = epochNo2013 w - epochWeek;
String mySQLtimestamp = /* 2013-09-23:50:00 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a normal `Date` all along?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
String output = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Desired output is `(String) "29-09-2013 23:50:00"`

Comment: @Ultra: I changed the answer. But default SQL datetime format is `2013-09-29 23:50:00`.

Comment: You are right, yet your solution returns wrong day: `265-09-2013 19:07:16` but it's easy to reformat with `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 5):

### *java.time*

With the release of Java SE 8 in March 2014, the outdated and error-prone legacy Date-Time API (`java.util` Date-Time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) was supplanted by `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API<sup>*</sup>. The [following table](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) depicts the mapping of ANSI SQL types with `java.time` types:

| ANSI SQL | Java SE 8 |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | LocalDate |
| TIME | LocalTime |
| TIMESTAMP | LocalDateTime |
| TIME WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetTime |
| TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetDateTime |

Note that `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` are not supported by any JDBC driver whereas some drivers e.g. PostgreSQL also do not support `OffsetTime` / `TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]`. Also, note that all `OffsetDateTime` instances will have to be in UTC (have offset 0). This is because the backend stores them as UTC.

### How to use it in JDBC?

Given below is a sample code to insert the current `OffsetDateTime` in UTC, into `columnfoo` (which is of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` type):

```
OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, odt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline and is independent of a timezone i.e. it has a timezone offset of `+00:00` hours.

Given below is a sample code to retrieve a `OffsetDateTime` from `columnfoo`:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <some condition>");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Assuming the column index of columnfoo is 1
    OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class));
    System.out.println(odt);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

**Just in case you need to convert an `OffsetDateTime` into another one with a different offset:**

There are several ways to do so but I mostly use [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-), to convert an `OffsetDateTime` into another one with a different timezone offset e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample OffsetDateTime in UTC.
        OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);

        OffsetDateTime offsetTimeAtOffset0100 = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
        System.out.println(offsetTimeAtOffset0100);

        // Time at JVM's default timezone offset
        ZoneOffset jvmTzOffset = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getOffset();
        OffsetDateTime offsetTimeAtJvmTzOffset = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(jvmTzOffset);
        System.out.println(offsetTimeAtJvmTzOffset);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-29T13:36:15.258076Z
2021-05-29T15:36:15.258076+02:00
2021-05-29T14:36:15.258076+01:00
```

Some points related to the code given above:

1. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).
2. The code converts `odt` into two instances of `OffsetDateTime` - each in a different way. The first instance is with a fixed timezone offset of `+02:00` hours whereas the second one is with the timezone offset of the JVM. Note that the timezone offset of a place observing [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) changes as per the summer/winter time. Therefore, if a place observes DST, instead of using a fixed timezone offset e.g. `+02:00` hours; we should get it from the API.
3. My JVM's timezone is `Europe/London` and currently its offset is `+01:00` hours.

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>