# Get first and last day of month using threeten, LocalDate

Tags: java, date, java-time

I have a LocalDate which needs to get the first and last day of the month. 
How do I do that?

eg. `13/2/2014`
I need to get `1/2/2014` and `28/2/2014` in [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) formats.

Using threeten LocalDate class.

Comment: Use: 

LocalDate start = YearMonth.now().atDay(1);
LocalDate end   = YearMonth.now().atEndOfMonth();

OR:

LocalDate startDay = Year.of(2020).atMonth(11).atDay(1);
LocalDate endDay = Year.of(2020).atMonth(11).atEndOfMonth();

Answer (score 271):

Just use `withDayOfMonth`, and `lengthOfMonth()`:

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13);
LocalDate start = initial.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate end = initial.withDayOfMonth(initial.getMonth().length(initial.isLeapYear()));
```

Comment: FYI see other answers

Answer (score 219):

The API was designed to support a solution that matches closely to business requirements

```
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.*;

LocalDate initial = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13);
LocalDate start = initial.with(firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate end = initial.with(lastDayOfMonth());
```

However, Jon's solutions are also fine.

Comment: Going with this one, uses the API resources specifically made to handle this particular problem.

Answer (score 162):

## `YearMonth`

For completeness, and more elegant in my opinion, see this use of [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth month = YearMonth.from(date);
LocalDate start = month.atDay(1);
LocalDate end   = month.atEndOfMonth();
```

For the first & last day of the current month, this becomes:

```
LocalDate start = YearMonth.now().atDay(1);
LocalDate end   = YearMonth.now().atEndOfMonth();
```

Comment: Best solution of all.

Comment: Extra info: YearMonth yearMonth =  YearMonth.parse("202004",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM"));

Comment: what are the advantages of it compared to `LocalDate` `with` method?

Comment: @AndrewBloom you don't need to use a static function to get the last day of the month, and at least in the second example, you don't need to have a `LocalDate` instance to start with.

Comment: is there something similar for getting the first/last day of the week?

Comment: @DennisVA if your week is Monday-to-Sunday, first day is `date.with(previousOrSame(MONDAY))` (static import from TemporalAdjusters).  Last day is `date.with(nextOrSame(SUNDAY))`.  Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 28):

Jon Skeets answer is right and has deserved my upvote, just adding this slightly different solution for completeness:

```
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth;

LocalDate initial = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13);
LocalDate start = initial.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate end = initial.with(lastDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, honestly, I don't understand the downvote because my answer was even one day before that of JodaStephen and pointed to the mainly interesting new part, namely the temporal adjuster for the end of month. That is I have not "copied" the answer from anyone else.

Comment: Great answer! This solution is better because it's recommended in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html): "...finding the first or last day of the month"

Answer (score 10):

```
 LocalDate monthstart = LocalDate.of(year,month,1);
 LocalDate monthend = monthstart.plusDays(monthstart.lengthOfMonth()-1);
```

Comment: Please describe your answer

Answer (score 7):

If anyone comes looking for **first day of previous month** and **last day of previous month**:

```java
public static LocalDate firstDayOfPreviousMonth(LocalDate date) {
        return date.minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
    }


public static LocalDate lastDayOfPreviousMonth(LocalDate date) {
        return date.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
    }
```

Comment: Good code, but in Stack Overflow an Answer should address the specifics of the Question.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. Sometimes we find related code in the thread, as I came looking for this as well. I just put it for such users. Hope that is okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
LocalDate endDate = startDate.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
```

or

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("startDate: "+startDate);
    
    LocalDate firstDayOfMonth_of_startDate = startDate.withDayOfMonth(1); 
    System.out.println("firstDayOfMonth_of_startDate: "+firstDayOfMonth_of_startDate);
    
    LocalDate firstDayOfNextMonth_of_startDate = firstDayOfMonth_of_startDate.plusMonths(1); 
    System.out.println("firstDayOfNextMonth_of_startDate: "+firstDayOfNextMonth_of_startDate);
    
    LocalDate lastDayOfTheMonth_of_startDate = firstDayOfNextMonth_of_startDate.minusDays(1); 
    System.out.println("lastDayOfTheMonth_of_startDate: "+lastDayOfTheMonth_of_startDate);

    // or everything in one line
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("endDate: "+endDate);
```

and the printouts

```
startDate: 2021-11-05
firstDayOfMonth_of_startDate: 2021-11-01
firstDayOfNextMonth_of_startDate: 2021-12-01
lastDayOfTheMonth_of_startDate: 2021-11-30
endDate: 2021-11-30
```

Comment: I updated my response. see above

Answer (score 3):

### Yet another solution for the last day of the month:

I have written this answer just for learners who want to learn by playing with various options. ***I do not recommend it for production use.***

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        System.out.println(lastDateOfMonth(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 13)));
        System.out.println(lastDateOfMonth(LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13)));
        System.out.println(lastDateOfMonth(LocalDate.of(2016, 2, 13)));
        System.out.println(lastDateOfMonth(LocalDate.of(2014, 4, 13)));
    }
    
    static LocalDate lastDateOfMonth(LocalDate date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31)
                                .appendPattern("uuuu-MM")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return LocalDate.parse(YearMonth.from(date).toString(), dtf);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2016-02-29
2014-04-30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Cf19wS)

#### How does it work?

The function, [`YearMonth#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#toString--) returns a string in the format, `uuuu-MM`, the format I have used with the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. I have defaulted the [`ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) to 31, the maximum number of days a month can have, and this works for all months.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it only with the LocalDate-class:

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13);

LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(initial.getYear(), initial.getMonthValue(),1);

// Idea: the last day is the same as the first day of next month minus one day.
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(initial.getYear(), initial.getMonthValue(), 1).plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to avoid indicating custom date and if there is need to display start and end dates of current month:

```
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.now().minusDays(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()-1);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.now().minusDays(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()).plusMonths(1);
    System.out.println("Start of month: " + start);
    System.out.println("End of month: " + end);
```

*Result:*

```
>     Start of month: 2019-12-01
>     End of month: 2019-12-30
```

Comment: It seems a bit overcomplicated to me. It also doesn’t give the correct result. The last day of this month is 2019-12-31, but your snippet printed 2019-12-30.

Comment: The answer itself is wrong, December ends on the 31st and not the 30th.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 13);
LocalDate start = initial.withDayOfMonth(1);         
LocalDate end = initial.withDayOfMonth(initial.getMonthOfYear().getLastDayOfMonth(false));
System.out.println(start);
System.out.println(end);
```

you can find the desire output but need to take care of  parameter **true/false** for **getLastDayOfMonth** method

that parameter denotes leap year

Comment: There's no need to use `getLastDayOfMonth` - see my answer for a simpler approach.

Comment: @Shekhar Rajput The question is about LocalDate from JDK not from JODA! Pay more attention!

Answer (score 0):

Just here to show my implementation for @herman solution

```
ZoneId americaLaPazZone = ZoneId.of("UTC-04:00");

static Date firstDateOfMonth(Date date) {
  LocalDate localDate = convertToLocalDateWithTimezone(date);
  YearMonth baseMonth = YearMonth.from(localDate);
  LocalDateTime initialDate = baseMonth.atDay(firstDayOfMonth).atStartOfDay();
  return Date.from(initialDate.atZone(americaLaPazZone).toInstant());
}

static Date lastDateOfMonth(Date date) {
  LocalDate localDate = convertToLocalDateWithTimezone(date);
  YearMonth baseMonth = YearMonth.from(localDate);
  LocalDateTime lastDate = baseMonth.atEndOfMonth().atTime(23, 59, 59);
  return Date.from(lastDate.atZone(americaLaPazZone).toInstant());
}

static LocalDate convertToLocalDateWithTimezone(Date date) {
  return LocalDateTime.from(date.toInstant().atZone(americaLaPazZone)).toLocalDate();
}
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to be using here. You are discarding valuable zone/offset information.

Comment: The Question asks for a date-only value, not the date-with-time values you seek here. And the terrible legacy class `Date` has nothing to do with the Question, and should generally be avoided.

Comment: For La Paz time zone please use the more correct `ZoneId.of("America/La_Paz")`. For present-day dates it will give the same result, but maybe not for historic dates or dates in a further future.

Comment: well, `atDay(firstDayOfMonth).atStartOfDay();` and `atEndOfMonth().atTime(23, 59, 59)` was exactly what i was searching for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use withDayOfMonth.
eg. LocalDateTime.now().withDayOfMonth(1)
this will give start of the month.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. When a `LocalDate` was asked about, what would be the point of using a `LocalDateTime` instead? You will be getting a time on the first day of the month, but if one intended the start of that day, you are not getting that.

Comment: User was asking for LocalDate and not LocalDateTime please update your answer accordingly