# How to get last three months first date and last date based on current date including current date in java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, localdate

I want to categorize values based on months so to filter those values required 1st & last date of last three months based on current month including current month values. Here how many last months is parameter. I wanted list of all months 1st date and last date. Any logic for the same will be helpful.

for example:-

```
     //     parameters 
          int lastMonths = 3;
          date currentDate= 26-04-2019;

 //expected output
 current month is 04-2019 ,1st date is 1-04-2019 and last date is 30-04-2019 
 previous month is 03-2019, 1st date is 01-03-2019 and last date is 31-03-2019
 previous month is 02-2019, 1st date is 01-02-2019 and last date is 28-02-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use **java.util.Calendar** for addition and subraction in date

and

> **java.text.DateFormat** to format date

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(format.parse("26-04-2019"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println("currentDate: " + monthFormat.format(cal.getTime())); // print current month

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println("first date: " + format.format(cal.getTime())); // print first date

        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        System.out.println("last date: " + format.format(cal.getTime())); // print last date


        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    }
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Answer (score 1):

Important to say - there are tons of libraries who will give you this specific need, but I would like relying on one that does the work and was actually designed for (some of yours...) those use cases -
**Java.time.LocalDate library (already built into Java 8)**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // 2019-04-26
```

In order to get first and last days of month, you can use:

```
LocalDate start = YearMonth.now().atDay(1);
```

(now can be some other month, of course)

```
LocalDate end = YearMonth.now().atEndOfMonth();
```

You can use it specifically on one / two months, or with some for loop. Examples below: 
**1. Specific call:**

```
LocalDate earlierOneMonth = now.minusMonths(1); // 2019-03-26
earlierOneMonth.getDay(); // 26
```

**2. For Loop: (so you'll need something like an array / list to store those values...)**

```
for(int i=0; i < lastMonths - 1; i++){
   arr(i) = now.minusMonths(i + 1);

}
```

Also, in order to get the name of the month, you can use ->

```
earlierOneMonth.getMonth(); // APRIL
earlierOneMonth.getMonth.getValue(); // 04
```

Lastly, in order to get the year, you can use ->

```
earlier.getYear(); // 2019
```

Once you have all of your desired values, you can print them out as you requested, with that expected output:

```
 "current month is" + nowMonth + "-" + nowYear + " ,1st date is" +  nowDay + "-" + nowMonth + "-" + nowYear + " and last date is ...
```

Let me know if it's clear enough :)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now().minusMonths( 3 ).atDay( 1 )      // Get the first day of the month of three months ago. Returns `LocalDate` object.
YearMonth.now().minusMonths( 3 ).atEndOfMonth()  // Get the last day of the month of three months ago. Returns `LocalDate` object.
```

## `YearMonth`

You really care about the months. The dates are secondary. So focus on the months. Java has a class for that!

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents a particular month of a particular year.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
YearMonth currentYm = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

Collect your months of interest.

```
List< YearMonth > yms = new ArrayList<>() ;
int limit = 3 ; // We want current month plus three previous months. 
for( int i = 0 ; i <= limit ; i ++ ) {
    YearMonth ym = currentYm.minusMonths( i ) ;
    yms.add( ym ) ;
}
```

When you need dates, loop the list. Let `YearMonth` determine the first and last days of the month.

```
for( YearMonth ym : yms ) {
    System.out.println( "YearMonth: " + ym + " starts: " + ym.atDay( 1 ) +  " ends: " + ym.atEndOfMonth() ) ; 
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/QZz9rR).

> YearMonth: 2019-04 starts: 2019-04-01 ends: 2019-04-30
>
> YearMonth: 2019-03 starts: 2019-03-01 ends: 2019-03-31
>
> YearMonth: 2019-02 starts: 2019-02-01 ends: 2019-02-28
>
> YearMonth: 2019-01 starts: 2019-01-01 ends: 2019-01-31

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Date object then the following will do just fine

```
        Date date = getDate(targetDate);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        // calendar.getTime()
        // The line above returns Date object
```

If you need a plain String then you can format it any way you want by simply using *DateTimeFormatter* from org.joda.time library and just use it's print() method on calendar.getTimeInMillis().

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int lastMonths = 3;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DateFormat monthYearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy");

    for (int i = 0; i < lastMonths; i++) {

        int monthOfYear = month - i;

        // if month is january, reset couter and month
        if(monthOfYear == 0) {
            month = 13;
            year -= 1;
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // get last day of month (month length)
        YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(year, monthOfYear);
        int firstDay = 1;
        int lastDay  = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();

        // create date with given year, month and day
        Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear - 1, firstDay).getTime();

        String monthAndYear = monthYearFormat.format(date);

        String currentOrPrevious;

        if (i == 0) {
            currentOrPrevious = "current";
        } else {
            currentOrPrevious = "previous";
        }

        String output = String.format("%s month is %s, 1st date is %02d-%s and last date is %d-%s", currentOrPrevious, monthAndYear, firstDay, monthAndYear, lastDay, monthAndYear);

        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
current month is 04-2019, 1st date is 01-04-2019 and last date is 30-04-2019
previous month is 03-2019, 1st date is 01-03-2019 and last date is 31-03-2019
previous month is 02-2019, 1st date is 01-02-2019 and last date is 28-02-2019
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by *java.time* with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 26);//current date
    System.out.println(currentDate);
    int lastMonths = 3;//number of months
    LocalDate prevDate = null;
    LocalDate start = null;
    LocalDate end = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < lastMonths; i++) {
        if(prevDate == null) {
            start = currentDate.withDayOfMonth(1);//First day of current month
            end = currentDate.withDayOfMonth(currentDate.lengthOfMonth());//Last day of current month
            prevDate = currentDate.minusMonths(1);//subtracting one month from current month 
        } else {
            start = prevDate.withDayOfMonth(1);//First day of previous month
            end = prevDate.withDayOfMonth(prevDate.lengthOfMonth());//Last day of previous month
            prevDate = prevDate.minusMonths(1);//subtracting one month from previous month
        }
        System.out.println(start + " " + end);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
2019-04-26
2019-04-01 2019-04-30
2019-03-01 2019-03-31
2019-02-01 2019-02-28
```

Reference: 
[Get first and last day of month using threeten, LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223786/get-first-and-last-day-of-month-using-threeten-localdate)