# Get the month last date

Tags: java, localdatetime

I have a LocalDateTime object I want to get the last date of the month. So if the localDateTime points to today's date of 29th October. I want to convert it to 31st October 
 Is there a clean and easy way to do it?

My Thoughts: 
One way would be to get the month and then make a switch statement. But that would be the long and tedious approach. Not sure if there is an inbuilt method 
 to do the same

Comment: A question: [Get first and last day of month using threeten, LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22223786/10819573).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 10, 29, 0, 0);
      LocalDateTime b = a.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
      
      System.out.println(a);
      System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I add the endTime of day to the localDateTime. I see an option called LocalTime.MAX but it adds trailing .99999

Answer (score 6):

Use [YearMonth.atEndOfMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--)

```java
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
YearMonth month = YearMonth.from(date);
LocalDate end = month.atEndOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> How do I add the endTime of day to the localDateTime. I see an option called LocalTime.MAX but it adds trailing .99999

Do not use `LocalDateTime` if you are tracking moments, specific points on the timeline. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. For moments, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Represent an entire month with [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

You should not try to nail down the last moment of the month. That last moment is infinitely divisible. Generally, the best way to define a span of time is the Half-Open approach rather than Fully-Closed. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So a day starts with first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *next* day. A month starts with the first moment of the first day of the month and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the first of the *next* month.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
YearMonth followingMonth = currentMonth.plusMonths( 1 ) ;

ZonedDateTime start = currentMonth.atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = followingMonth.atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

To represent that span of time, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. Use the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class with its handy comparison methods such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, and `contains`.

```
org.threeten.extra.Interval interval = Interval.of( start.toInstant() , end.toInstant() ) ;
```