# Select statement between two java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, date

my code is:

```
    java.sql.Date fromDate= new java.sql.Date(date1);
    java.sql.Date toDate= new java.sql.Date(date2);

    String select = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date between " + fromDate+ " and" + toDate;
```

I´m using Derby database, and I have to run this query but return error. How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: "but return error" is *never* enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before you ask your next question.

Comment: Sorry, is my first question.

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html), released in March 2014. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) which are based on the modern Date-Time API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, *stop building SQL like that*. It's vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), conversion issues (which is probably the problem here) and it's hard to read.

Use parameterized SQL instead:

```
// TODO: Close the statement, e.g. using a try-with-resources statement
// or a finally block.
PreparedStatement statement =
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date between ? and ?");
statement.setDate(1, fromDate);
statement.setDate(2, toDate);
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
// Use the results
```

This may well be enough to fix the problems immediately. If it's not, please give more details.

Comment: @MartinGian, You should accept this answer as it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). The JDBC tutorial includes [plenty of examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

While we are on the subject, this may be a good time to learn about [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (obligatory [xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/327/)).