# Conversion from UTC to IST returning same value in JAVA using Joda time library

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I need to convert TimeZone in my project from UTC to IST and vice versa. For that purpose I am using Joda time jar in my project. But the problem occurs when I try to convert the string from UTC to IST, I am getting the same value instead of getting converted IST value. Kindly please mentor me in which part of code I am completely stuck up. My code is as follows:

```
public class JodaDemo {

    public static final String DATE_PATTERN_SERVICE = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    public static final String DATE_PATTERN_SERVICE_NO_SECONDS = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getDateFromUTCtoIST("2015-08-23 10:34:40");

    }
private static void getDateFromUTCtoIST(String dateTime) {

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_PATTERN_SERVICE);
        DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime);
        DateTimeZone indianTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
        DateTime indianTime = jodatime.withZone(indianTimeZone);

        System.out.println(indianTime);

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2015-08-23T10:34:40.000+05:30
```

**Expected output:**

Converted TimeZone (+5:30 output) like in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly, when you're parsing the value you're not specifying the time zone - so it's using your local time zone. Secondly, you're not using any formatter for the result - you're just calling `DateTime.toString()`, implicitly.

The simplest approach is actually to create two formatters for the same pattern, one in UTC and one in the relevant time zone - then you don't need to manually convert at all, as the formatter can do it for you:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {

  public static final String DATE_PATTERN_SERVICE = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        DateTimeFormatter utcFormatter = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern(DATE_PATTERN_SERVICE)
            .withLocale(Locale.US)
            .withZoneUTC();
        DateTimeZone indianZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
        DateTimeFormatter indianZoneFormatter = utcFormatter.withZone(indianZone);

        String utcText = "2015-08-23 10:34:40";
        DateTime parsed = utcFormatter.parseDateTime(utcText);
        String indianText = indianZoneFormatter.print(parsed);
        System.out.println(indianText); // 2015-08-23 16:04:40
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. This is simply awesome and it is working great. Also if possible can you please help me to do vice versa method (i.e from IST to UTC). I will accept this answer. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Chandru: Well to do the reverse, just parse with `indianZoneFormatter` and print with `utcFormatter`... but note that in time zones which observe daylight saving time (I know the Indian time zone doesn't, at the moment) this can lead to ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks got it. Implemented successfully.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2015-08-23 10:34:40";
        
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdtIndia);

        OffsetDateTime odt = zdtIndia.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-08-23T16:04:40+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2015-08-23T16:04:40+05:30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YKOwem)

**Some important notes:**

1. If you are going to deal with JDBC, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.
2. For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
    Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>