# Converting java.sql.Timestamp to Instant Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, instant, sql-timestamp

From my database i retrieve value as :

```
20-DEC-17 10.15.53.000000000 AM
```

I want above `java.sql.Timestamp` to be converted to Instant time as :

```
2017-12-20T10:15:53Z
```

---

I tried following with current time stamp

```
Timestamp ts2 = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
Date tradeDate1=new Date(ts2.getTime());
Instant tradeInstant = tradeDate1.toInstant();
System.out.println("Tade Instant"+ tradeInstant);
```

- Actual time stamp: `Fri Jun 22 16:07:35 IST 2018`
- What is prints in instan : `Tade Instant2018-06-22T10:37:35.420Z`

The `hours/mins/seconds` are updated which I dont want - is there a way this can be retained as is?

Comment: Please correct your typos. It's really hard to understand the paragraph after your code-snippet.

Comment: One is printing the time in local time zone (IST), the other is printing it in UTC (`0Z`), would seem to be correct

Comment: If your timestamp value is correct, then you don’t have an issue. The `Instant` denotes the same point in time. Any other conversion — like one that printed the same hour of day in UTC as in IST — would be incorrect. However, the best solution would be to retrieve the `Instant` directly from the database and avoid the `Timestamp` class altogether. It’s long outmoded. Are you using JDBC and a `ResultSet`?

Comment: Are you saying that `20-DEC-17 10.15.53.000000000 AM` is already in UTC so that converting it from IST to UTC is incorrect?

Comment: Thats right, the value retrieved from DB is already in UTC and its stored as timestamp - can i retrieve this value as result.getInstant to ensure i dont loose precision of seconds ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer understood - however assuming that timestamp value would be coming from database (which is already UTC) - i want to ensure the hours mins and seconds are not updated .. unfortunately I want this of type Instant cause my ultimate POJO accepts instant object.

Comment: @ImranMoosani Also understand that the values been printed are using an internal formatter used to provide "human readable" results, the classes them selves are just a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (at least in the case of `Timestamp`).  How you "format" the information is more important, this is why the API has `DateTimeFormatter`

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2. I am further assuming that the timestamp doesn’t have time zone or offset information in the database, but is to be understood as a timestamp in UTC (which is a recommended practice). In this case I would consider it safest to add the information about UTC offset explicitly in Java:

```
PreparedStatement yourPreparedStatement 
            = yourConnection.prepareStatement("select trade_timestamp from your_table");
ResultSet rs = yourPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    LocalDateTime tradeDateTime = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class);
    Instant tradeInstant = tradeDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
    System.out.println("Trade Instant: " + tradeInstant);
}
```

Note that the code avoids the outdated `Timestamp` class completely. A `LocalDateTime` is a date and time of day without time zone or offset. If your database datatype had been `timestamp with time zone`, you could have passed either `Instant.class` or `OffsetDateTime.class` to `rs.getObject` and have got an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime` back. JDBC 4.2 only specifies support for `OffsetDateTime`, but many drivers support `Instant` too. Obviously with `Instant` you need no further conversion. With `OffsetDateTime` do

```
    Instant tradeInstant = tradeDateTime.toInstant();
```

Depending on your database and its capabilities it is also possible that you can set UTC as offset/time zone on the database session so you can get the correct instant even from `timestamp` without time zone.

**Discussion:** Arvind Kumar Avinash in a comment recommends that one should rely only on the types officially supported by JDBC 4.2, that is, `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` for our purposes. The types are mentioned at the bottom of the article *Why do we need a new date and time library?* on Oracle’s web site, there’s a link at the bottom. Arvind Kumar Avinash further refers us to *PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.Instant*, also linked to at the bottom. Since comments are fragile, I wanted to include the essence here in the answer.

### What went wrong in your code?

It seems your database session understood the timestamp as a date and time in your local time zone (IST, I assume it’s for India Standard Time (other interpretations exist)). According to Mark Rotteveel’s informative comment this behaviour is required by JDBC, but it doesn’t agree with your need when the value is in UTC. Therefore it gave you the wrong point in time, though it looked right when you printed it. The conversion in itself was correct.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Why do we need a new date and time library?](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)
- [PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.Instant.](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/1095) on doobie’s GitHub page (doobie is a JDBC layer for Scala)

Comment: thanks for detail explaination. I believe I am having a better understanding of how this Instant and LocalDateTime are behaving. I will try on same lines and hopefully this should now work as expected. Thanks again !!

Comment: _"It seems your database session incorrectly understood the timestamp as a date and time in your local time zone"_ that behavior is actually required by JDBC (for timestamp without timezone).

Comment: *If your database datatype had been `timestamp with timezone`, you could have passed `Instant.class` to rs.getObject and have got an `Instant` immediately and would not have hat to convert.* - This is wrong. The only supported `java.time` types are `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetTime`, and `OffsetDateTime`. Also, some DBs do not support `LocalTime` and `OffsetTime`.

Comment: **For future visitors:** This is the correct answer except for the problem that I have pointed out in the above comment. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) for the list of `java.time` supported types in JDBC. These two answers solve different problems and one should go through both of them to understand scenarios for using `LocalDate/LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Better but I still recommend that one should rely only on the types given at the bottom of [this page](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). A driver can be implemented to support `Instant` but I would still stick to the spec even while using that driver.

Comment: I like portable code myself, so clearly see your point, @ArvindKumarAvinash. On the other hand `Instant` makes such great sense here. For many purposes it’s what you want. So I find it fine to offer both possibilities. Please let your comment stand, your opinion is valuable.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the nice comment. I liked your spirit. **Just for the information to the future visitors**: [PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.Instant. #1095](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/1095)

Answer (score 0):

Building from the comment about not using SimpleDateFormat, I have moved to DateTimeFormatter:

```
Date today = new Date();

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") // same format
        .withLocale(Locale.UK) // UK locale
        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

String output = dateTimeFormatter.format( today.toInstant() );

System.out.println( output );
```

Running gives you:

```
2018-06-22T14:14:26
```

Comment: A clear improvement over your first answer, IMHO. A tip: `Timestamp` too furnishes [a `toInstant` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--). With that I don’t think you need the rest.

Answer (score -2):

I have created a SimpleDateFormat, which only prints "up to seconds":

```
/* simple date format */   
DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

/* get toInstant() and convert to date */
Date myDate = Date.from(today.toInstant());

/* myDate formatted using DATE_FORMAT */
String formattedDate = DATE_FORMAT.format(myDate);

System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Please refer to my new answer, which uses DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Thanks, I may be hard to please, though, I have not understood how it answers the question.