# Good practices with java.time - how to represent datetime in my dto/entity/model classes?

Tags: java, jpa, time, dto

For simplicity let's assume we're talking about a classic web application that has backend written in Java, has a SQL database and communicates through REST.

My question is: What is the best `java.time` class to represent some point in time (e.g. time when a comment was posted) in a data structure-like class (DTO, JPA Entity, Model)? I've already seen it all: `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `Date`, `Instant`. Especially `LocalDateTime` as a field in JPA Entity just doesn't feel right. What should be used? ZonedDateTime? OffsetDateTime? Instant? "Good" old java.util.Date and convert it into some `java.time` object only when some date calculations are needed?

Comment: This question will get closed because it is primarily opinion based and is so very broad because you've not disclosed any use case requirements at all. For instance, is there a requirement to store Time Zone information with the time? That is unlikely the case for a "classic web app".

Comment: Disagree.  This is a question with a single correct answer.

Comment: Check [How to convert epoch to mySQL timestamp in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19080655/10819573) and [Dates with no time or timezone component in Java/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285553/10819573) and [Converting java.sql.Timestamp to Instant Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986138/converting-java-sql-timestamp-to-instant-time/50987372#comment119913322_50987372).

Comment: There is nothing "good" about `java.util.Date` (nor `Calendar`). The terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Your Question has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. Just search for the class names you mentioned to learn much more. Short answer: To represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use `Instant` as shown in Answer by Wasserman. For presentation to the user, adjust to a time zone by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. For communication with a database, use `OffsetDateTime` as the type matching the SQL standard's concept of a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. For a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

An unambiguous, unmoving point in history is always correctly represented as an `Instant`, which is a point in physical time.

In your scenario, it might particularly make sense for this `Instant` to appear differently depending on the time zone of the person who asked: for example, if the comment was posted five minutes ago, any user looking at that comment should see a time that is five minutes before their local time.