# What is better to persist in database: OffsetDateTime or Instant?

Tags: java, postgresql, java-time

I want to save a timestamp value into PostgreSQL database. Corresponding column is of the type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

As input Java application gets epoch time (`long` value), that could be converted into `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

What is the best approach? Are there any drawbacks with any of this method?

Comment: The correct corresponding Java class is `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: While `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` does live up to (down to?) *without time zone*, it doesn’t live up to *timestamp* since it doesn’t uniquely define a point in time. If there’s a way you can, use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` instead (which lives up to *timestamp* but not really to *with time zone*).

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Answer (score 12):

### Short answer

As per the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/), [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) is not supported. But you shouldn't have issues with [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) in UTC.

---

### Long answer

The [PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/) mentions that a corresponding type for `TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]` is [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), but [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) in UTC is also supported. On the other hand, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) is not supported.

See the quote below:

> ```
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> | PostgreSQL™                    | Java SE 8      |
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> | DATE                           | LocalDate      |
> | TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]      | LocalTime      |
> | TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ] | LocalDateTime  |
> | TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE        | OffsetDateTime |
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> This is closely aligned with tables B-4 and B-5 of the JDBC 4.2 specification.
>
> **Note**
> `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` and `OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]` are not supported. Also note that all `OffsetDateTime` will instances will have be in UTC (have offset 0). This is because the backend stores them as UTC.

And the [JDBC 4.2 specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/jdbc4.2-fr-spec.pdf) mention support for [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

---

Also see the following quote from the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class documentation (highlight is mine):

> `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` all store an instant on the time-line to nanosecond precision. Instant is the simplest, simply representing the instant. `OffsetDateTime` adds to the instant the offset from UTC/Greenwich, which allows the local date-time to be obtained. `ZonedDateTime` adds full time-zone rules.
>
> It is intended that `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` is used to model data in simpler applications. **This class may be used when modeling date-time concepts in more detail, or when communicating to a database or in a network protocol.**

Comment: I see that Instant is not supported. Is this wrong to use it?

Comment: But the quote says, "_Note that `ZonedDateTime`, **`Instant`** and `OffsetTime` / `TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]` are **not** supported_".

Comment: @Slaw [totally embarrassed here] I don't know where my mind is today. I completely misinterpreted that statement. Let me fix that.

Comment: From OffsetDateTime documentation I see the following: "It is intended that {@code ZonedDateTime} or {@code Instant} is used to model data
 in simpler applications. This class may be used when modeling date-time concepts in more detail, or when communicating to a database or in a network protocol." Very confusing. My problem is that I'm actually using Instant and it works, but I need to know if have any guarantee on it.

Comment: @mvb13 As per documentation, you are advised to use either `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @mvb13 *Do not* use Instant unless the corresponding column is a `WITH TIMEZONE` column.  You do not want the database driver making assumptions about what timezone to use and converting your data in a way that might or might be correct.

Comment: While support for `Instant` is not *required* by JDBC 4.2 & 4.3, a JDBC driver implementation can choose to support that type. Conversion is trivially easy for such a driver to implement using `Instant#atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )` and `OffsetDateTime#toInstant`. Using `Instant` with such a JDBC driver would be convenient but would make your code less portable.

Comment: Adding the updated [JDBC documentation link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/#using-java-8-date-and-time-classes)