# How to solve parse exception when timezone has colon?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I am receiving `DateTime` as a `String` from a webservice. An example of this `DateTime` string is: `"DateTime":"2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00"`.

This `2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00`  more or less matches the ISO-8601 format, so I have used this pattern to parse it: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. However, the colon in the timezone part of the response DateTime is causing issues. `2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00` is giving parse exception, but `2021-06-06T04:54:41-0400` is parsing fine.

Below code should explain it better:

```
public void stringToDate() {

        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";  //ISO - 8601 Format
        TimeZone timeZoneEST = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("en", "US"));
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        sdf.setTimeZone(timeZoneEST);
        
        String timeFromWebService = "2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00";
        try {
            Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(timeFromWebService); // not working because of colon in timezone part
            System.out.println(parsedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);  //sleep to avoid interleaving output from stacktrace (above) and syso (below)
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        String timeFromWebServiceModified = "2021-06-06T04:54:41-0400";  //removed colon from timezone part
        try {
            Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(timeFromWebServiceModified); // working because colon is removed in timezone part
            System.out.println(parsedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

I want to handle this parsing without modifying the response `DateTime`. Any suggestions on how I can parse the original `DateTime`. Any suggestion on what pattern to use will be very help full.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its one-arg `parse` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d'T'H:m:s[XXX][XX][X]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-0400",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-04",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41Z"                  
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00
2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00
2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00
2021-06-06T04:54:41Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/bZ0pp5)

Check [How to use `OffsetDateTime` in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080655/how-to-convert-epoch-to-mysql-timestamp-in-java/67752047#67752047).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Solution using legacy API:**

`SimpleDateFormat` does not have a feature to specify optional patterns, the way we do, using the square bracket, with `DateTimeFormatter`. In this case, you can create multiple instances of `SimpleDateFormat` and try with each one.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sfdArr[] = {
                            new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:sXXX", Locale.ENGLISH),
                            new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:sXX", Locale.ENGLISH),
                            new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:sX", Locale.ENGLISH)
        };
        
        String []strDateTimeArr = {
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-04:00",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-0400",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41-04",
                    "2021-06-06T04:54:41Z"                  
        };
        
        for(String s : strDateTimeArr) {
            Date date = null;
            for(SimpleDateFormat sdf : sfdArr) {
                try {
                    date = sdf.parse(s);
                }catch(ParseException e) {
                    //...
                }
            }
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/i1dJbc)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: right said. I am Moving to j8+ api going forward :-).  Here's another issue I am seeing with j8+ api - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861911/java-datetimeformatter-iso-offset-date-time-output-differs-from-java-doc

Comment: could you up vote the Q if you think it's worth it.