# Java DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME output differs from Java Doc

Tags: java, java-time

from [java 11 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) for ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

> The ISO date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with an
> offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'.

1. But when i use a DateTimeFormatter with the above formatting i am seeing different output.
2. Setting timezone for DateTimeFormatter seems to have no effect.

Below code should clarify it -

```
public void j8DateTimeWithFormatter() {
        DateTimeFormatter odtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        String zdt = ZonedDateTime.now().format(odtf);       
        System.out.println(zdt);  // Output 2021-06-06T22:44:28.4410102+05:30 //what is this 4410102, is it nano seconds or some thing else. How to not see this. 
       
        //further
        odtf.withZone(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern")); 
        zdt = ZonedDateTime.now().format(odtf); 
        //after setting the zoneid to EST why am i still seeing time in IST
        System.out.println(zdt);  // Output 2021-06-06T22:44:28.4430055+05:30
    }
```

How to fix these? Please advice. I want to still use `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` and see the output as in docs -  2021-06-06T22:44:28-04:00

Comment: Yes, these are nanoseconds. If you read further in the Documentation, the format consists of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`, which includes `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`. This includes nanoseconds if they are present. If you test your code with a DateTime which has no nanoseconds, they wont be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is this 4410102, is it nano seconds or some thing else. How to
> not see this.

This is *fraction-of-second*. If you do not want to see it, truncate the value to seconds.

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(odtf));
```

> after setting the zoneid to EST why am i still seeing time in IST

Because `DateTimeFormatter` is immutable and you need to assign the new value as follows:

```
odtf = odtf.withZone(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf));

        // If you do not want nano seconds
        zdt = zdt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf));

        // Formatting to a different timezone
        dtf = dtf.withZone(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(dtf));

        // However, I recommend
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-06T18:45:06.604419+01:00
2021-06-06T18:45:06+01:00
2021-06-06T13:45:06.607643-04:00
2021-06-06T13:45:06-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: i don't want the nano seconds (and even the doc does not mention the nano seconds in the output). How can i get them not to come in output.

Comment: For the sake of precision, 4410102 is a fraction of second and not exactly nanoseconds. Since there are 1 000 000 000 nanos in a second, the fraction is equal to 441 010 200 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is intended behavior.

The docs use the words "such as", which means the example is, well, an example, and thus the output may differ.

The docs mention that the format consists of ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME and the offset. The ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME in turn consists of the ISO_LOCAL_DATE, the letter 'T' and the ISO_LOCAL_TIME.

And if we then look at th docs for the ISO_LOCAL_TIME:

> One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

There it is. The format by default outputs necessary nanos.