# Convert OffsetDateTime to LocalDateTime with correct offset in java 8

Tags: java, time, timezone

When I try to convert `OffsetDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` from java.time, I expect the resulting `LocalDateTime` to be updated with the local time zone. So, If I have an `OffsetDateTime` of `2011-12-03T10:00:00Z`, and my local timezone is UTC+2, I expect the LocalDateTime to be `2011-12-03T12:00:00`, but I get instead `2011-12-03T10:00:00`. I'm converting it with the method `toLocalDateTime()` that `OffsetDateTime` has. It seems that it only truncates the date, removing the offset part, without adjusting the time.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to get a `LocalDateTime` that represents the local date time taking into account the zone offset. Following the example, I would like to get `2011-12-03T12:00:00`

Comment: It's a bit unclear about what you mean by "the local time zone". Keep in mind that you are working with _offset_ date times, not _zoned_ date times, so I'll assume you mean "the local offset". However, that is ambiguous. Do you mean the local offset at the instant `2011-12-03T10:00:00Z`, or do you mean the local offset _now_? Note that local offsets can change.

Comment: *"It seems that it only truncates the date, removing the offset part, without adjusting the time"* .. that's correct and that's what the method description says (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--). Also, the "local" part in `LocalDateTime` doesn't mean it bothers about your actual local timezone, it just means that it represents a time that is valid for any current local timezone/offset, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LocalDateTime would give you the time of a wall clock of your OffsetDateTime. That's 10:00

You need to first convert to a ZonedDatedTime in your time zone

Like this

```
OffsetDateTime off = OffsetDateTime.of(2011,12,3,10,00,0,0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime zoned = off.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Athens"));
LocalDateTime athensWallTime = zoned.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(athensWallTime);
```

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is [`OffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:00:00Z")
    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalDateTime()
```

Comment: Will this convert it depending on OS time?

Answer (score 4):

## [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-)

If you need to convert an object of `OffsetDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime` object with a different `ZoneOffset`, you can do so by using `OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:00:00Z");

        OffsetDateTime odtWithOffsetTwoHours = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
        System.out.println(odtWithOffsetTwoHours);

        LocalDateTime ldt = odtWithOffsetTwoHours.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-12-03T12:00+02:00
2011-12-03T12:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wzOpgw)

I suggest you keep using `OffsetDateTime` because `LocalDateTime`, as the name suggests, throws away the useful timezone information. Nevertheless, `LocalDateTime` is useful in some scenarios as mentioned on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html).

If you are dealing with JDBC, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as correct put me in the right direction to make it a little bit more production oriented. Also, I need this for Kotlin, so considering it is retro-compatible, here it goes.

For me, what worked was using `withOffsetSameInstant`. This method requires the offset, and I think the key is to obtain it from the system to provide the user with the visualization in its own time.

The offset can be obtained like this:

```
val offset = OffsetDateTime.now().offset
```

And then we proceed to parse the date-time text to `OffsetDateTime`:

```
val dateTime = "2023-01-20T01:00:00+00:00"

val offsetDateTime =  OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime).withOffsetSameInstant(offset)
```

Then we can obtain the local date-time like this:

```
val localDateTime = offsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime()
println(localDateTime)
```

Let's say that my offset is minus 3 (-03:00). Then that should print:

```
2023-01-19T22:00
```

This, for me, seems ok because it was day 20th at 1:00 am, so with minus 3, it should be the day 19th.

A small clarification regarding using a formatter. For the format above, you don't need to provide a `DateTimeFormatter` because the method `parse` with a single argument; assumes it is ISO, and the format above is ISO (`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`).

This is how you can create a formatter in case you need it:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the most concise solution is

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is some code you can try :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT1 = OffsetDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime1: " + offsetDT1);
 
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT2 = OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime2: " + offsetDT2);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT3 = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime3: " + offsetDT3);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT4 = OffsetDateTime.of(1980, 4, 9, 20, 15, 45, 345875000, ZoneOffset.of("+07:00"));
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime4: " + offsetDT4);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT5 = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(15, 50, 25), ZoneOffset.of("+07:00"));
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime5: " + offsetDT5);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT6 = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneOffset.of("+07:00"));
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime6: " + offsetDT6);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT7 = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime7: " + offsetDT7);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT8 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-31T15:20:30+08:00");
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime8: " + offsetDT8);
        
        OffsetDateTime offsetDT9 = OffsetDateTime.parse("1980-04-09T08:20:45+07:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime9: " + offsetDT9);
```

**Output**

```
OffsetDateTime1: 2019-08-31T23:49:05.629+08:00
OffsetDateTime2: 2019-08-31T15:49:05.630Z
OffsetDateTime3: 2019-08-31T22:49:05.630+07:00
OffsetDateTime4: 1980-04-09T20:15:45.345875+07:00
OffsetDateTime5: 2019-08-31T15:50:25+07:00   
OffsetDateTime6: 2019-08-31T23:49:05.631+07:00
OffsetDateTime7: 2019-08-31T23:49:05.631+08:00
OffsetDateTime8: 2019-08-31T15:20:30+08:00
OffsetDateTime9: 1980-04-09T08:20:45+07:00
```

You can take a look on this [website](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/java/java-offsetdatetime-tutorial-examples/) for more explaination or browse [javadoc wbsite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalDate--).

Comment: Which part of all that code is supposed to be an answer to the question?

Comment: According to the output I given, you can choose one function you want to use.

Comment: And which of those *changes* `2011-12-03T10:00:00Z` (type `OffsetDateTime`) to `2011-12-03T12:00:00` (type `LocalDateTime`)? There is no `LocalDateTime` in this answer, and there is no conversion of a `OffsetDateTime` for changing the time from 10 to 12, so that would be: None of them.

Comment: For #7, `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault())` is the long way of saying `OffsetDateTime.now()`.