# Date Object in different Timezone other than servers default timezone | Timezone aware datetime object in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, timezone

My Server is running on UTC timezone, I want to save time of any operation in database in IST format, I tried various ways including following.

```
Date ISTDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")).getTime();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
jobRepository.save(new IncremetalJob(ISTDate,ISTDate, JobState.IN_PROGRESS));
```

Everytime UTC date is being saved, can someone suggest here.

Comment: I recommend you keep it in UTC. Also, do not use the error-prone legacy date-time API. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67918503/10819573) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30651210/10819573) can also be helpful to you.

Comment: A time zone aware datetime object in Java is a `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead as hinted use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).