# How to check if timestamp between two timestamps postgres?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring api where I am using postgres and saving a field of type timestamp with field name as `created_date`. Now I want to check whether this field is between two different timestamps.

Right now I am using this:

```
 select *
from your_table
where created_date >= '2020-06-22 19:10:25-07'
and created_date < '2020-06-23 19:10:25-07'
```

Is there a way I can use `BETWEEN` here for this operation?

Comment: Why don't you just check this in the business logic layer?

Comment: I am using this to search for all the records that have date between this range,I am doing this in the Repository layer.

Comment: You do not want to use `between`.  It includes both end points and that is probably not what you intend.  Your current version is probably the right way to write the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  your_table
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2020-06-22 19:10:25-07'
AND '2020-06-23 19:10:25-07'
```

If you want to do it using JDBC, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573).

Comment: thanks but will it work if the second param in BETWEEN in empty string,will it return the record with condition matching with first param? first param=first timestamp, second param=second timestamp

Comment: `BETWEEN` requires two values. If you want to work with only the first value, you can use `SELECT *
FROM  your_table
WHERE created_date  >= '2020-06-22 19:10:25-07'`.