# How to find the timezone id for a time from a string for example "19-Jul-21 1:08:22 PM BST"?

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to make timestamps from a csv of timestamp strings,

eg `"21-Mar-21 05:01:26 GMT" and "19-Jul-21 1:08:22 BST"`

`SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss")`
gets the Date.

Is it possible to get the ZoneId from the "GMT" or "BST" strings? (BST being British Summer Time)

or do I need to hardcode a structure mapping one to the other?

Comment: Yo mean this? SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") add the Z to have the timezone on the date

Comment: Note that these "not really time zone" abbreviations aren't unique. "CST" can mean various different things, for example. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations. If you can *possibly* avoid using these abbreviations, it's good to do so.

Comment: That’s delicate. While *GMT* is probably unambiguous, *BST* has a lot of possible meanings beside British Summer Time (Brazil(ian) Summer Time, Bangladesh Standard Time, Bougainville Standard Time).

Comment: Is there a more global solution? Your answers include hard-coding Locale.ENGLISH or ZoneId.of("Europe/London"), what if my application is running in Germany or Turkey and I only have the abbreviated timeZone in the string to go on?

Comment: If you only have the abbreviation, give up, sorry. Those abbreviations are *very often* ambiguous, and your user will prefer a message saying you can’t interpret the abbreviation over a false result from interpreting the abbreviation wrongly.

Comment: Your string examples are in English. In Germany and Turkey they would probably use completely different date and time formats, so we’d need to know what those formats are.

Comment: Thank you, Ole v.v I thought that "give up" would be the answer, I just wanted to be sure. I shall make sure the CSV file is in UTC time + offset

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. Since `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`, it inherits all undesirable things from its parent type. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "21-Mar-21 05:01:26 GMT";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uu HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Getting ZoneId
        ZoneId zoneId = zdt.getZone();
        System.out.println(zoneId);

        // If required, get OffsetDateTime from the ZonedDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-21T05:01:26Z[GMT]
GMT
2021-03-21T05:01:26Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jgpubC)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

#### If at all you need `java.sql.Timestamp`:

For any reason, if you need `java.sql.Timestamp`, simply get `Instant` out of the `ZonedDateTime` and derive the value of `Timestamp` using [`Timestamp#from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(zdt.toInstant());
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

If you just need `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can do it in the following alternative easier way:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "21-Mar-21 05:01:26 GMT";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uu HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Instant instant = Instant.from(dtf.parse(strDateTime));
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-21 05:01:26.0
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uqSRb8)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### Update:

This update is based on the following valuable comment by [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v):

> `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd-MMM-uu H:mm:ss ").appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Set.of(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))).toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)`
> parses `19-Jul-21 1:08:22 BST` into
> `2021-07-19T01:08:22+01:00[Europe/London]`, which agrees with what the
> OP wanted. The mentioned datetime string has 1 digit hour of day, `1`,
> so we need just one `H` (which in turn also accepts the `05` from the
> other string example).

**Demo:**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "19-Jul-21 1:08:22 BST";
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uu H:mm:ss ")
                .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Set.of(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        Instant instant = Instant.from(dtf.parse(strDateTime));
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-21 05:01:26.0
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Z6EAVL)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `GMT` and `BST` are the only time zone abbreviations you will need, and you know for a fact that *British Summer Time* is the intended interpretation of *BST*, you can safely use the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

If there may be more time zone abbreviations in your input and you also know the correct interpretation for those, extending the answer is not difficult. Just pass a larger set of preferred time zones to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText()`. For the sake of the example for the following formatter I have specified that BST is British Summer Time, PST is for Pitcairn Standard Time and CST means Cuba Standard Time.

```
    Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = Set.of(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"),
            ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pitcairn"), ZoneId.of("America/Havana"));
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uu H:mm:ss ")
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If you don’t know which time zone abbreviations may turn up in your data or you are not sure of the correct interpretation of each one of them, I think that’s it’s better to give up on the task. Sorry. Those abbreviations are *very often* ambiguous. Rather than a false result from interpreting the abbreviation wrongly your users will prefer a message stating that you cannot interpret the time zone abbreviation.

Link: [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/).