# How to change Java Date timezone from server local timezone to a different timezone for a spring boot native query?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have records in a db with a column created_date saved as timestamp without time zone. Front-end users are based in +05.30 timezone. Back-end is hosted in Singapore. So the created_date date values are 5.30 hours behind the user's time.

How do i properly select a set of records that got created within a given day.

Eg: if the user is requesting data on 16-oct-2021, server needs to return the data with the created_date between 2021-10-16 00:00:00 and 2021-10-16 23:59:59:999 in their local time which is +05.30

I have a native query written for this as below,

`select * from records rr where rr.created_date at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' between ?1 and ?2`

I get the date 1 and 2 with the following code, which is giving the required data set only after 05.30am in users's timezone (+05.30)

```
Calendar startDate = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        
Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
endDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
endDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
endDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
endDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

Date fromDate = startDate.getTime();
Date toDate = endDate.getTime();
```

So, Assuming that i need to convert the startDate and endDate to the user's local timezone before passing as parameters for the query, i did the following,

```
Calendar startDate = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")); // convert from server timezone to user's local timezone
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
startDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);   
                        
Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
endDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
endDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
endDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
endDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

Date fromDate = startDate.getTime();
Date toDate = endDate.getTime();
```

This still doesn't return me the correct data set. If i directly run the below query on pgadmin i can get the results

```
select * from records rr where rr.created_date at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' between '2021-10-16 00:00:00' and '2021-10-16 23:59:59'
```

How do i get the same data set with my code? Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy. `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted years ago by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> column created_date saved as timestamp without time zone

That is the wrong data type for recording moments. Specific points on the timeline must be written to a column of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not `WITHOUT`.

Postgres uses the offset-from-UTC or time zone info supplied with any input to adjust to UTC. Values in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Postgres are always in UTC, always.

You said:

> run the below query on pgadmin

Unfortunately, many tools including pgAdmin have the anti-feature where they apply some default time zone to adjust the value retrieved from the database. This gives the false illusion of the value having been stored with a particular time zone. But as I said, values in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Postgres are always in UTC, always. I suggest always setting the pgAdmin session default time zone to UTC.

Never use `Calendar` or `Date`. Use only *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2 or later.

The time zone `Asia/Calcutta` has been renamed to `Asia/Kolkata`.

If you want the start and end of a day as seen in modern India :

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = today.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

We are using the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time, usually best for date-time work.

Convert to `OffsetDateTime` before passing to your `PreparedStatement`, to use a data type appropriate to SQL.

```
OffsetDateTime startOdt = start.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

You wrote:

> `Calendar startDate = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance();`

No need to cast here. That method already returns a `Calendar` object, so casting is pointless. (And, never use `Calendar`.)

I’ve been brief here, as this topic has already been addressed many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Correct. To the OP: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.